# Find full path of the Python interpreter (Python executable)?

Tags: python, path

How do I find the full path of the currently running Python interpreter from within the currently executing Python script?

---

<sub>See [How do I check which version of Python is running my script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1093322) if you are specifically interested in the *version* of Python for the currently running interpreter - for example, to bail out with an error message if your script doesn't support that Python version, or conditionally disable certain modules or code paths.</sub>

Answer (score 969, accepted):

`sys.executable` contains full path of the currently running Python interpreter.

```py
import sys

print(sys.executable)
```

which is now [documented here](https://docs.python.org/library/sys.html)

Comment: This does not seem to work from scripts with a shebang `/usr/bin/env python` executed as `env -i ./script`. In that case it returns the current working directory.

Comment: @JohnFreeman: I tried this on a GNU/Linux box w/ GNU coreutils 8.4 (env) and Python 3.4.2.  `#!/usr/bin/env python3` will return the correct full binary path via `sys.executable`.  Perhaps your OS or Python version behaves slightly differently.

Comment: Note that this will not return the name of the Python interpreter if Python is embedded in some application.

Comment: I tried this with the shebang for python2 and python3 and it printed the correct executable. I also tried with no shebang and called the script with the `python` and `python3` commands and it printed the correct executable.

Comment: It doesnt seem to work, if you have created an alias for python through alternatives, i.e. alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python2 50
      alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3.5 60    
      alternatives --config python
In this case, sys.executable still prints python2 path.

Comment: typing ```type -a python3``` into the console gives me /usr/local/bin/python3,  /usr/bin/python3. Yet running ```import sys print(sys.executable)``` gives me /usr/local/opt/python@3.8/bin/python3.8 So the paths do not match. What's up with that?

Comment: @mic_e, this may have been true in 2015, but I just tried it today and it behaves as expected (it returns the absolute file of the executable that embeds Python).

Comment: @mic_e how to find python executable when embedded in an interpreter?

Answer (score 14):

Just noting a different way of questionable usefulness, using [`os.environ`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/os.html#os.environ):

```
import os
python_executable_path = os.environ['_']
```

e.g.

```
$ python -c "import os; print(os.environ['_'])"
/usr/bin/python
```

Comment: useless but funny :) (perhaps also not portable)

Comment: It seems that `_` is set by the shell. But it need not be set, so this could give the wrong answer.

Comment: FYI, when in a Jupyter notebook, this gives the path to the kernel launcher script.

Comment: `_` can be `/usr/bin/screen` if Python is run inside a GNU Screen.

Comment: Also, running Python with `sudo`  does not create the `_` environment variable.

Comment: Does not work on Windows (10). The environment variable `_` is not set.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few alternate ways to figure out the currently used python in Linux is:

1. `which python` command.
2. `command -v python` command
3. `type python` command

Similarly On Windows with Cygwin will also result the same.

```
kuvivek@HOSTNAME ~
$ which python
/usr/bin/python

kuvivek@HOSTNAME ~
$ whereis python
python: /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/python3.4 /usr/lib/python2.7 /usr/lib/python3.4        /usr/include/python2.7 /usr/include/python3.4m /usr/share/man/man1/python.1.gz

kuvivek@HOSTNAME ~
$ which python3
/usr/bin/python3

kuvivek@HOSTNAME ~
$ command -v python
/usr/bin/python

kuvivek@HOSTNAME ~
$ type python
python is hashed (/usr/bin/python)
```

If you are already in the python shell. Try anyone of these.
Note: This is an alternate way. Not the best pythonic way.

```
>>> import os
>>> os.popen('which python').read()
'/usr/bin/python\n'
>>>
>>> os.popen('type python').read()
'python is /usr/bin/python\n'
>>>
>>> os.popen('command -v python').read()
'/usr/bin/python\n'
>>>
>>>
```

If you are not sure of the actual path of the python command and is available in your system, Use the following command.

```
pi@osboxes:~ $ which python
/usr/bin/python
pi@osboxes:~ $ readlink -f $(which python)
/usr/bin/python2.7
pi@osboxes:~ $ 
pi@osboxes:~ $ which python3
/usr/bin/python3
pi@osboxes:~ $ 
pi@osboxes:~ $ readlink -f $(which python3)
/usr/bin/python3.7
pi@osboxes:~ $
```

Comment: "from within the currently executing Python script" wrote the OP

Comment: Your "already in the python shell" examples, all assume that the python shell started is what you get if you type `python` from the shell. If you start with an explicit different path (e.g. `/opt/python/2.5/bin/python`), or use `python3` and then run those python commands, **all of them produced incorrect answers** and that has nothing to do with not being the most pythonic way, it is just plain wrong.

Comment: Does not answer the question of "How do I find the full path of the currently running Python interpreter from within the currently executing Python script?"

Comment: **Dumpster fire answer.** There's *no* deterministic relation between what the external shell considers to be `python` (i.e., the absolute filename of the `python` command in the current `${PATH}`) and the command the active Python interpreter is actually running under. *Yikes.*