# Twisted app fails with error "Failed to load application: No module named OpenSSL.SSL" on OS X

Tags: python, python-2.7, ssl, openssl, twisted

When running a Twisted (OS X 10.9.3) file via `twistd -n -y chatserver.py` it fails with error:

```
...line 40, in <module>
    from OpenSSL.SSL import Error, ZeroReturnError, WantReadError
exceptions.ImportError: No module named OpenSSL.SSL

Failed to load application: No module named OpenSSL.SSL
```

Twisted and ssl import fine in a python shell:

```
python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Oct 26 2012, 16:12:44) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple Clang 4.0 ((tags/Apple/clang-421.0.60))] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import twisted
>>> import ssl
>>> exit()
```

Any pointers in the right direction?

Thanks!

Comment: You haven't provided enough information to diagnose the problem.  You've probably installed some alternate Python or done something weird though; pyOpenSSL is pre-installed on OS X.  What Python are you running, are you using virtualenv, are you using pip, or easy_install, etc?

Comment: Specifically on 10.9.3 if I import OpenSSL.SSL and [print the path](http://stackoverflow.com/a/248862/3334178) I get: /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/OpenSSL/SSL.so If your running a modern version of OS X (and not running a virtualenv/brew/port/fink) I suspect you've corrupted the builtin python packages.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By the information provided, I would assume you either:

- don't have pyOpenSSL loaded (the error said it was trying to import "OpenSSL.SSL", you tried importing "ssl", I don't know if "ssl" maps to pyOpenSSL).  See [twisted's TLS docs](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/ssl.html).

or

- your twistd is running a different instance of python then what you get at the terminal prompt

**Update:**

Given the feedback in the comments, and following the info from SO: [Retrieving python module path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247770/retrieving-python-module-path/248862) and [Find full path of python interpreter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2589711/find-full-path-of-python-interpreter)

Try running the following to see your current python paths:

For twistd put the following in a file and run it the same way your currently running twistd:

```
from twisted.application.service import Application
from twisted.internet import reactor
import sys

def print_path():
    print "   ----    The path to the twistd python is: " + str(sys.executable) + "   ----"
    reactor.stop()

application = Application("path_test")
reactor.callWhenRunning(print_path)
```

For your command line python just run the following in interactive mode:

```
import sys
print sys.executable
```

In my case (running OS X 10.9.3, with a somewhat customized python I get)

twistd:

```
% twistd -n -y twisted-question-24191967.py
2014-06-13 11:08:19-0400 [-] Log opened.
2014-06-13 11:08:19-0400 [-] twistd 13.2.0 (/usr/bin/python 2.7.5) starting up.
2014-06-13 11:08:19-0400 [-] reactor class: twisted.internet.selectreactor.SelectReactor.
2014-06-13 11:08:19-0400 [-]    ----    The path to the twistd python is: /usr/bin/python   ----
2014-06-13 11:08:19-0400 [-] Main loop terminated.
2014-06-13 11:08:19-0400 [-] Server Shut Down.
```

Interactively:

```
>>> import OpenSSL.SSL
>>> print OpenSSL.SSL.__file__
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/OpenSSL/SSL.so
>>> import sys
>>> print sys.executable
/usr/bin/python
```

Comment: I get a `Requirement already satisfied` when trying to install pyopenssl via pip but `from OpenSSL import SSL` still throws an error: `No module named OpenSSL`

Comment: So quite probably the latter explanation.  Just for the record, `ssl` and pyOpenSSL/`OpenSSL` are entirely separate things.