# How to make the third party library twisted of python automatically complete in sublime?

Tags: python, sublimetext3, twisted, sublime-text-plugin

I have installed package 'Anaconda' in sublime. But it doesn't work for third library like twisted and so on...How can I make it automatically complete? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> By default, anaconda uses the python interpreter that is in your **PATH
>   environment variable**, the most important configuration option is the
>   python_interpreter option that allow the user to use a different
>   python interpreter, for example, one that resides in a virtual
>   environment:

So check your sublime3 configuration, and make sure the python interpreter is right:

e.g.

```
{
    "font_face": "Monaco",
    "font_size": 11,
    "python_interpreter": "/Users/**/venv/bin/python"
}
```

[image]

See more details from [anaconda settings](http://damnwidget.github.io/anaconda/anaconda_settings/).

Comment: Thank you and it's amazing.My configuration is "python_interpreter": "python" but I don't know what is a right path.

Comment: What does "/Users/**/venv/bin/python" mean?

Comment: @周俊佐 It's the path of Python interpreter for me.Have a look at [Find full path of the Python interpreter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2589711/find-full-path-of-the-python-interpreter)

Comment: Excuse me, I have a new problem now.When I import `twisted.internet.reactor` like this `from twisted.internet import reactor`,and then type in `reactor.` there have not methods like `run` either `listenTCP`. Do you know what's the matter?