# flask-sqlalchemy failing to import in interpreter

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, virtualenv

I am writing a flask app in VisualStudio. The first lines of my `__init__.py` file for the application are:

```
import os
from flask import Flask
from config import Config
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
```

When I launch the application it opens in my webbrowser (locally) without any fuss. However, if I open an interpreter and write:

`from app import app`

it fails as it says that there is no module called flask_sqlalchemy. I am using a virtual env and I can see that Flask-SQLAlchemy is installed. When I do pip install it says that the requirement is already satisfied.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you switching to the venv in the command line before running the command?

Comment: I am opening the command line at the venv...Moreover, in the command line if I run `pip list` then Flask-SQLAlchemy is there

Comment: try to use the full python path of this specific venv, and post results.

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: When you are in the interpreter [check that it is the interpreter from your virtual env](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2589722/6560549).

Comment: You are right on the money, it is not my virtual env. This is odd. When I run the app from visual studio it evidently runs from the virtualenv, but when I open the command prompt it does not. This is weird as I installed the packages into the virtualenv, in the command prompt. I guess i need to change it back

Answer (score 0):

Try install within pipenv with:

```
pipenv shell 
pipenv install package_name
```