# How can I write a command for linux machine to find out python path

Tags: python, linux

I want to create a python program which on running gives me the python path in the linux environmental variable. In windows I am doing below way -

```
import os
try:
    user_paths=os.environmen['path'].split(os.pathstep)
excepterror:
    user_paths=[]
print(user_paths)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2589722/6317430

Using the sys package:

```
import sys
print(sys.executable)
```

Comment: Thanks @siralexsir88. It helped