# Why I get an ImportError while importing cairo if the installation seems to be correct?

Tags: python, cairo, pycairo

The issue is quite simple. I've installed Python and Cairo with Homebrew since I use a M1 MacBook. When trying to import the package, I get this error:

```
>>> import cairo
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cairo/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from ._cairo import *  # noqa: F401,F403
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cairo/_cairo.cpython-39-darwin.so, 2): Symbol not found: _cairo_append_path
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cairo/_cairo.cpython-39-darwin.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cairo/_cairo.cpython-39-darwin.so
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at [this issue](https://github.com/pygobject/pycairo/issues/226#issuecomment-783531283) over on their GitHub, and in particular [this comment](https://github.com/pygobject/pycairo/issues/226#issuecomment-783531283), you could try a couple things:

- Use Python 3.9 if you're not already (and use `python3` in the terminal)
- Uninstall `pycairo` as you have it now and install `py3cairo` with homebrew
- Create a new venv with `python3` and the `--system-site-package` option i.e. `python3 -m venv --system-site-package path/to/env`

Check out the comment itself, and let me know if any of this works. There didn't seem to be one clear solution for the issue.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for the answer. I try the three methods (well, I was already using python3) but nothing work, I keep getting the exact same error.

Comment: Anything else on that issue help out? Such as the steps he took with homebrew

Comment: Otherwise I suggest commenting on that issue again that the fixes did not resolve your issue and hopefully one of the maintainers can help you out

Comment: I read the issue and what I've noticed is that I'm not sure if when running python3 with the terminal it is running the version I have installed with Homebrew. How do I ensure this?

Comment: Either check the version to make sure it's the right one with `python3 --version` or check if the executable is the one you want to use ([use this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2589722/14316282) to find the executable it's running).