# How can I install Requests for Python

Tags: python, module, python-requests

```
Requirement already satisfied: requests in c:\users\16dea\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (2.25.1)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<3,>=2.5 in c:\users\16dea\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from requests) (2.10)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<5,>=3.0.2 in c:\users\16dea\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from requests) (3.0.4)     
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in c:\users\16dea\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from requests) (2020.6.20)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.27,>=1.21.1 in c:\users\16dea\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from requests) (1.25.11)
```

I unistalled anaconda, i have unistalled and reinstalled requests, restarted Visual Studio Code, restarted my laptop after unistalling Anaconda. I have tried installing it through Command Prompt, and IDE. But When I run the code it says requests does not exist

Comment: It's installed. The question is, are you using a Python version that knows to *look* in the Anaconda installation?

Comment: and how do I do that? And I removed anaconda from my computer so why would I still have it?

Answer (score 0):

This scenario is most likely related to different python versions on your computer.

Like shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2589711/find-full-path-of-the-python-interpreter) you can get the interpreter you are actually using as follows

```
import sys
print(sys.executable)
```

Comment: C:\Users\16dea\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe

I got this now what do  I need to check

Comment: compare this to the path you get from your install (c:\users\16dea\anaconda3\lib\site-packages) you recognize that those are not the same thus you run a wrong python-interpreter

Comment: try localizing your anaconda python interpreter in `c:\users\16dea\anaconda3\..` and use this one