# How do I update a Python package?

Tags: python, linux, installation, package, m2crypto

I'm running Ubuntu 9:10 and a package called M2Crypto is installed (version is 0.19.1). I need to download, build and install the latest version of the M2Crypto package (0.20.2).

The 0.19.1 package has files in a number of locations including (/usr/share/pyshared and /usr/lib/pymodules.python2.6).

How can I completely uninstall version 0.19.1 from my system before installing 0.20.2?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You might want to look into a Python package manager like [pip](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/).  If you don't want to use a Python package manager, you should be able to download M2Crypto and build/compile/install over the old installation.

Comment: Thanks. What you said worked. I built and installed 0.20.2 without needing to uninstall 0.19.1.

Answer (score 623):

The best way I've found is to run this command from terminal

```
sudo pip install [package_name] --upgrade
```

`sudo` will ask to enter your root password to confirm the action.

---

Note: Some users may have pip3 installed instead. In that case, use

```
sudo pip3 install [package_name] --upgrade
```

Comment: And if you are using a proxy without authentication: sudo pip install [package] --upgrade --proxy=address:port

Comment: I came here for this answer. I tried `pip update` and `pip upgrade` and was desperate until I saw `--upgrade` here. Why don't they add a `pip upgrade` command?

Comment: This is indeed a well-hidden feature.

Comment: For Windows users: `sudo` is not required.

Comment: This should be answer #1

Comment: For people who is using a server without root privilege, try `pip3 install [package_name] --upgrade --user`

Answer (score 57):

To automatically upgrade all the outdated packages (that were installed using pip), just run the script bellow,

```
pip install $(pip list --outdated | awk '{ print $1 }') --upgrade
```

Here, `pip list --outdated` will list all the out dated packages and then we pipe it to awk, so it will print only the names.
Then, the `$(...)` will make it a variable and then, everything is done auto matically. Make sure you have the permissions. (Just put `sudo` before pip if you're confused)
I would write a script named, `pip-upgrade`
The code is bellow,

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo pip install $(pip list --outdated | awk '{ print $1 }') --upgrade
```

Then use the following lines of script to prepare it:

```
sudo chmod +x pip-upgrade
sudo cp pip-upgrade /usr/bin/
```

Then, just hit `pip-upgrade` and voila!

Comment: i got a syntax error pointing to the last bracket in: `awk: cmd. line:1: { print $1 })`

Comment: @TT Newer versions of `pip` require you to use the `--format=legacy` option, i.e., `pip list --outdated --format=legacy`. Also FYI everyone: blindly updating all modules via pip can be quite dangerous on many Linux distros. Many of them provide specific python modules via distro packages and some of those distros (RHEL in particular) can break hard if you updating shit ... not to mention the fact that if you update via pip, the distro packages might revert your changes on a future update.

Comment: thanks @rsaw. He's right you should run your pip commands with the --user option

Comment: `legacy` was an invalid format for me in PIP 19.0. Recommended alternative: `pip install --upgrade --user $(pip list --outdated --user --format=freeze | cut -d'=' -f1)` (_Yes, I am terrible with awk, hence the usage of cut._) Leave out `--user` where appropriate depending on your needs.

Comment: I like this answer, though I understand the danger in updating everything automatically. Anyway, since legacy is deprecated in pip 19.0
pip install $(pip list --outdated --format=columns | grep -v "Package" | grep -v -- ---- | awk '{ print $1 }') --upgrade

Comment: In order to work on an Ubuntu 18.04 venv adapt as follows: `pip install $(pip list --outdated | tail +3 | grep -v sdist | awk '{ print $1 }') --upgrade`

Comment: why is this not a built in feature of pip?

Comment: @SamJohnson sorry for replying 2.5 years late but this is primarily due to compatibility. If you upgrade and a package has breaking changes, then upgrading would result your program to become dysfunctional.

Answer (score 44):

1. Via windows command prompt, run: `pip list --outdated`
   You will get the list of outdated packages.
2. Run: `pip install [package] --upgrade`
   It will upgrade the `[package]` and uninstall the previous version.

---

To update pip:

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

Again, this will uninstall the previous version of pip and will install the latest version of pip.

Comment: You can omit "py -m" part.

Answer (score 40):

- Method 1: Upgrade manually one by one

---

```
pip install package_name -U
```

- Method 2: Upgrade all at once (high chance rollback if some package fail to upgrade

---

```
pip install $(pip list --outdated --format=columns |tail -n +3|cut -d" " -f1) --upgrade
```

- Method 3: Upgrade one by one using loop

---

```
for i in  $(pip list --outdated --format=columns |tail -n +3|cut -d" " -f1); do pip install $i --upgrade; done
```

Answer (score 14):

I think the best one-liner is:

```
pip install --upgrade <package>==<version>
```

Answer (score 10):

Open Command prompt or terminal and use below syntax

```
pip install --upgrade [package]==[specific version or latest version]
```

For Example

```
pip install --upgrade numpy==1.19.1
```

Answer (score 4):

How was the package originally installed? If it was via apt, you could just be able to do `apt-get remove python-m2crypto`

If you installed it via easy_install, I'm pretty sure the only way is to just trash the files under lib, shared, etc..

My recommendation in the future? Use something like [pip](http://pip.openplans.org/) to install your packages. Furthermore, you could look up into something called [virtualenv](http://pip.openplans.org/) so your packages are stored on a per-environment basis, rather than solely on root.

With pip, it's pretty easy:

```
pip install m2crypto
```

But you can also install from git, svn, etc repos with the right address. This is all explained in the [pip documentation](http://pip.openplans.org/)

Comment: The way he describes where the files are installed indicates that the package was installed using the apt package manager - because (on Debian AFAIK) apt would install python packages under the 2 locations he listed - /share/pyshared/.. is for shared code across versions and /usr/lib/.. for version specific parts. easy-install/pip on the other hand would use /usr/local/lib/.. - so as you said - just apt-get remove would've done him.

Answer (score 4):

```
pip install -U $(pip list --outdated | awk 'NR>2 {print $1}')
```

Comment: You should improve your answer by adding an explanation. Especially it needs clarification, how [this differs from already given answers.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45917517/8881141)

Answer (score 3):

In Juptyer notebook, a very simple way is

```
!pip install <package_name> --upgrade
```

So, you just need to replace  with the actual package name.

Answer (score 3):

> How can I completely uninstall version 0.19.1 from my system before
> installing 0.20.2?

In order to uninstall M2Crypto use

```
pip uninstall M2Crypto
```

---

> I need to download, build and install the latest version of the
> M2Crypto package (0.20.2).

In order to install the latest version, one can use [PyPi](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=M2Crypto&t=fpas&ia=web)

```
pip install M2Crypto
```

To install the version 20.2 (an outdated one), run

```
pip install M2Crypto==0.20.2
```

---

Assuming one just wants to upgrade

```
pip install M2Crypto --upgrade # Or pip install M2Crypto -U
```

---

Notes:

- Depending on one's Python version ([here's how to find the version](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1093322/7109869)) one may use a different pip command. Let's say one is working with Python 3.7, instead of just using `pip`, one might use `pip3.7`.
- Using `sudo` is considered [unsafe](https://dev.to/elabftw/stop-using-sudo-pip-install-52mn).
- Nowadays there are better practices to manage the development system, such as: virtual environments or development containers. The development containers allow one to put the entire development environment (be it modules, VS Code extensions, npm libraries,...) inside a Docker container. When the project comes to an end, one closes the container. There's no need to keep all of those requirements around in the computer for no reason. If you feel like reading more about it: [Visual Studio Docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers), [Github](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-dev-containers).

Answer (score 2):

Get all the outdated packages and create a batch file with the following
commands
pip install xxx --upgrade for each outdated packages

Answer (score 0):

I.e.:

```
python -m pip install --proxy <proxyserver_name>:<port#> <pkg_name>
```

Remember to export the variables after setting them, to make them available to the outer shell session.

Windows:

## Add to environment variables:

```
set HTTP_PROXY=<proxyserver_name>:<port#>
```

You might have to install the full python package first