# how to use re.findall to find the words that is NOT of all uppercase letters?

Tags: python, regex, findall

For example I have `s="I REALLY don't want to talk about it, not at all!"`

I want `re.findall(reg, s)` to return 
`"I"  "don't"  "want" "to" "talk" "about" "it" "," "not" "at" "all" "!"`

So far I got `reg=r'[^\w\s]+|\w+|\n'`   which can not filter out the word `"REALLY"`

thanks

Comment: Do you mean only ASCII uppercase or any uppercase letters (`Я`, `Г`, etc)? Try `r'[^\w\s]+|\b(?![A-Z]{2,}\b)\w+|\n'` if you only mean to work with ASCII chars.

Comment: Also, "I" is all uppercase.

Comment: See mu answer below, it should work for you.

Comment: It works for me: re.findall(r"\b['\w]*[a-z]+[\w']*\b",s)

Answer (score 2):

The `\w+` pattern matches 1 or more any word chars, including words in ALLCAPS.

Note that `I`, a pronoun, is also ALLCAPS. Thus, assuming you want to skip all ALLCAPS words of 2 or more letters, you may consider fixing your current pattern as

```
r'[^\w\s]+|\b(?![A-Z]{2,}\b)\w+|\n'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1apfIA/1)

The `\b(?![A-Z]{2,}\b)\w+`  pattern matches

- `\b` - word boundary
- `(?![A-Z]{2,}\b)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if, immediately to the right of the current location, there are 2 or more ASCII uppercase letters followed with a word boundary
- `\w+` - 1 or more word chars (if you only want to match letters, replace with `[^\W\d_]+`).

To support all Unicode uppercase letters, you may use PyPi regex with `r'[^\w\s]+|\b(?!\p{Lu}{2,}\b)\w+|\n'` pattern, or build the class using `pLu = '[{}]'.format("".join([chr(i) for i in range(sys.maxunicode) if chr(i).isupper()]))` (Python 3) or `pLu = u'[{}]'.format(u"".join([unichr(i) for i in xrange(sys.maxunicode) if unichr(i).isupper()]))` (Python 2). See [Python regex for unicode capitalized words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36187349). Note I'd recommend sticking to the latest Python versions or the latest PyPi regex modules.

Comment: thanks!  is there any recommended book/document on reg expression with very nice explanations just like the one you wrote here ?

Comment: @SoManyProblems No idea which part of the answer you refer to. To see a specific regex description, go to regex101.com. To learn regex in general, there is a nice ["Mastering Regular Expressions" book written by J. Friedl](http://ww2.ii.uj.edu.pl/~tabor/prII09-10/perl/master.pdf).

Comment: @SoManyProblems If this solution worked for you please consider accepting the answer.

Answer (score 1):

This quote by Brian Kernighan is especially true for regular expressions.

> Everyone knows that debugging is twice as hard as writing a program in
>   the first place. So if you're as clever as you can be when you write
>   it, how will you ever debug it?

So if something is difficult to do in a single regular expression, you might want to split it into two steps. Find all words first, and then filter out the all uppercase words. Easier to understand and easier to test.

```
>>> import re
>>> s="I REALLY don't want to talk about it, not at all!"
>>> words = re.findall(r"[\w']+", s)
>>> words = [w for w in words if w.upper() != w]
>>> print(words)
["don't", 'want', 'to', 'talk', 'about', 'it', 'not', 'at', 'all']
```