# Iterate over list of strings to pull out substrings

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I have a long list of different strings that all contain some information about a specific port across the globe. However, each port name is different and is contained in a different location within the string. What I want to do is loop over all of the strings, find the word `'Port'` and then store the next two substrings after `'Port'`. For example:

```
'Strong winds may disrupt operations at the Port of Rotterdam on July 5'
```

I find `'Port'` and now want `'of Rotterdam'` to be added onto `'Port'` as a complete string, like `'Port of Rotterdam'`. I thought there could be some way to split up each longer string by doing `parts = my_str.split(' ')`. Then:

```
for i in parts:
    if i == 'Port':
        new_str = i
```

However, I am not sure how to add on the next two substrings. Ideas?

Comment: Is it actually always two substrings?

Comment: No, not necessarily. But I think most of the time it should be. I'm not sure how I would control for situations where it isn't though.

Comment: You could also match Port followed by a single "word" and optionally a second for example `\bPort\s+\S+(?:\s+\S+)?` https://regex101.com/r/OatSlU/1

Comment: I've updated my answer further, with a better regex solution as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [`list.index`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) (also documented [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations)):

```
parts = my_str.split(' ')
try:
    port_index = parts.index('Port')
except ValueError:
    pass # Port name not found
else:
    port_name = ' '.join(parts[port_index:port_index + 2])
```

You can of course do more advanced processing. For example, grab a sequence of uppercased words optionally preceded by a single `of`:

```
def find_name(sentence):
    """
    Get the port name or None.
    """
    parts = sentence.split(' ')
    try:
        start = parts.index('Port')
    except ValueError:
        return None
    else:
        if start == len(parts) - 1:
            return None

    end = start + 1
    if parts[end] == 'of':
        end = end + 1
    while end < len(parts) and parts[end][0].isupper():
        end += 1

    if end == start + 1 or (end == start + 2 and parts[start + 1] == 'of'):
        return None

    return ' '.join(parts[start:end])
```

Of course you can do the same thing with regex:

```
pattern = re.compile(r'Port(?:\s+of)?(\s+[A-Z]\S+)+')
match = pattern.search(my_str)
print(match.group())
```

This regex will not properly match non-latin uppercase letters. You may want to investigate the solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36187349/2988730) for sufficiently foreign port names.

Both of the solutions here will work correctly for the following two test cases:

```
'Strong winds may disrupt operations at the Port of Rotterdam on July 5'
'Strong winds may disrupt operations at the Port of Fos-sur-Mer on July 5'
'Strong winds may disrupt operations at Port Said on July 5'
```

You can likely improve the search further, but this should give you the tools to get a solid start. At some point, if the sentences become complex enough, you may want to use natural language processing of some kind. For example, look into the [nltk](https://www.nltk.org/) package.

Comment: Your last regex solution is really neat. Is there a way to amend it so the name of the port can include dashes? For example, Port of Fos-sur-Mer.

Comment: @EliTurasky. Sure. I've edited the answer. You can add builtin classes into manually constructed classes: `[\w-]` is totally valid. I've chosen to be even less restrictive and just changed `\w` to `\S`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use list comprehension to get the 2 next tokens -

```
l = 'Strong winds may disrupt operations at the Port of Rotterdam on July 5 and Port of London is closed tomorrow'

tokens = l.split()
ports = [' '.join(tokens[i:i+3]) for i in range(len(tokens)) if tokens[i]=='Port']
print(ports)
```

```
['Port of Rotterdam', 'Port of London']
```

The benefit of this approach is that it can find multiple Ports in the same sentence.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use a pattern to match Port followed by a "word" that consists of non whitespace charactes and optionally a second word if the second is not always present.

```
\bPort\s+\S+(?:\s+\S+)?
```

- `\bPort` Match `Port` preceded by a word boundary
- `\s+\S+` Match 1+ whitespace characters and 1+non whitespace characters
- `(?:\s+\S+)?` Optionally match a second word

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ay6sqk/1)

Example code

```
import re
pattern = r"\bPort\s+\S+(?:\s+\S+)?"
s = "Strong winds may disrupt operations at the Port of Rotterdam on July 5"
print(re.findall(pattern, s))
```

Output

```
['Port of Rotterdam']
```

Comment: This won't work for a sentence like `"Strong winds may disrupt operations at Port Said on July 5"`. Not a requirement by OP, but still a reasonable nice to have.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Why would it not work? https://regex101.com/r/tQ1Lcm/1 The question states `store the next two substrings after 'Port. ` so it does work.

Answer (score 1):

.split() creates a list with every item being a new word of the list. Then iterate through the list and find the position with "Port". If a Port has been found, a new string is created.

```
parts = 'Strong winds may disrupt operations at the Port of Rotterdam on July 5'
words = parts.split()
new_str = None

for i, word in enumerate(words):
    if word == "Port":
        new_str = words[i + 1] + " " + words[i + 2]

if new_str:
    print(new_str)
```