# Regex pattern with accented characters

Tags: python, regex, filter, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get the words that start with a capital letter regardless of whether it has a special character or not in the word. Currently, my pattern only gets capital letters without accents.

I don't need numbers or hyphens, just accents or special characters in the letters.

```
pattern = r"\b[A-Z][a-z]*\b"
name = soup.select('h1.data-header__headline-wrapper')[0].text.strip()
name = re.findall(pattern, name)
name = " ".join(name)
```

Some examples. Special characters should be included to correctly return player 1 and 4.

```
�lvaro Fern�ndez
[]

#3                    
                                            Rico Henry
['Rico', 'Henry']
Rico Henry
#24                    
                                            Tariqe Fosu
['Tariqe', 'Fosu']
Tariqe Fosu
#29                    
                                            Mads Bech S�rensen
['Mads', 'Bech']
Mads Bech
```

Comment: Could you provide an example string of what is going in and what you'd like to extract?

Comment: These are names of players from various leagues. For example, the extraction is "#3 Álvaro Fernández" and I would like to get "Álvaro Fernández". @GeneBurinsky

Comment: I second Gene Burinsky's comment here, please do add samples of input and expected output more clearly in your question; to make it more clear. thank you.

Comment: Examples added. Player 2 and 3 are correct. @RavinderSingh13

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `pip install regex` in your console and then use

```py
import regex
pattern = r"\b\p{Lu}\p{Ll}*\b"
name = soup.select('h1.data-header__headline-wrapper')[0].text.strip()
name = regex.findall(pattern, name)
name = " ".join(name)
```

Here,

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `\p{Lu}` - an uppercase letter
- `\p{Ll}*` - zero or more lowercase letters.

**If you cannot install the PyPi regex module** you need to build ranges of  upper- and lowercase letters (based on [Python regex for unicode capitalized words](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36187349/3832970)):

```py
import sys, re
pLu = '[{}]'.format("".join([chr(i) for i in range(sys.maxunicode) if chr(i).isupper()]))
pLl = '[{}]'.format("".join([chr(i) for i in range(sys.maxunicode) if chr(i).islower()]))
pattern = fr"\b{pLu}{pLl}*\b"
name = soup.select('h1.data-header__headline-wrapper')[0].text.strip()
print ( " ".join( regex.findall(pattern, name) ) )
```

See [this Python demo](https://tio.run/##rZExbsMwDEV3nYJwh0hF4KVzhyJrtoxxBtmRYxUyRdAymtTw0LHH6BGKHsEHc@XEcKcCHQoBhPApPpJfdAmVx4dxtDV5DsDmZM6CdAiGER6BkyzPqNu2/RRdf5/liUBdm5hLhve8gOENUcMTkTOwGT5qzRo2nvXr8IWwM8On56XiSk9Li0ftnJy7rGHKqoUKSfrsLcqbSmwxzHdxFwmgidjrohLzyM2lWUdd0LaN5at91x9Waem51kEmM2tfVCytgiiDBYvAGk9GxtK01ucWbeGPRoEt4fYwtU1LZFiqg4ozbN1/kp1/WciL0eXkdBd36GOYfb7uDvLHkt8M/PtPKIhHjOM3).

Comment: It is not working. It jumps error when it reaches the character with accent. "re.error: bad escape \p at position 2"

Comment: @Carlos Did you install the PyPi regex module? See "***You need to `pip install regex` in your console***". See [the Python demo online](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzO3IL@oRKEoNT21gqsgsaQktShPwVahSCkmKaag2qe0FkTm1GrFJClx5SXmpgLllA53JiUrHG7My0tUcCwoyElVcD68MDexKFHBOb8oserw5jyF4NTDG/OL4DrApuulZealJObkaEBt0VEAyWrCTVVQ0svKz8zTgIgWFGXmlUDY//8DAA).

Comment: @Carlos I added a `re` based solution if you cannot afford another dependency in the project.

Comment: Yeah, but it's not working. Same error. It´s not including the special characterds

Comment: @Carlos Show me your code using tio.run. See [my code is working](https://tio.run/##rZExbsMwDEV3nYJwh0hF4KVzhyJrtoxxBtmRYxUyRdAymtTw0LHH6BGKHsEHc@XEcKcCHQoBhPApPpJfdAmVx4dxtDV5DsDmZM6CdAiGER6BkyzPqNu2/RRdf5/liUBdm5hLhve8gOENUcMTkTOwGT5qzRo2nvXr8IWwM8On56XiSk9Li0ftnJy7rGHKqoUKSfrsLcqbSmwxzHdxFwmgidjrohLzyM2lWUdd0LaN5at91x9Waem51kEmM2tfVCytgiiDBYvAGk9GxtK01ucWbeGPRoEt4fYwtU1LZFiqg4ozbN1/kp1/WciL0eXkdBd36GOYfb7uDvLHkt8M/PtPKIhHjOM3).

Comment: The second option worked. Thanks!!