# Problem with Regex password verification with default android keyboard layouts such as Japanese and Russian keyboards

Tags: java, android, regex

I used Regex to verify a password with a minimum of 8 characters containing 1 uppercase, 1 lowercase, 1 special character, and 1 numeric value. The problem I encountered is that if people from Russia or any other country whose language is different from English try to enter the password using the default keyboard, it will create a problem for them.

Currently i have set this regex condition for my application :

```
String regex = "^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[#?!@$%^&*-]).{8,}$";
```

It works if the user sets the password in English. But it does not work if the user's language is different. (A password like `Испытание@123` will fail).
I searched on google about russian regex for the default keyboard and found a solution for the russian keyboard.

> Do i need to work out for all different language for password validation
> regex?

Is there an alternative solution so that I can check the password check for any default keyboard layout with the password validation that I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\p{Ll}` to match any Unicode lowercase letters and `\p{Lu}` to match any Unicode uppercase letters:

```java
String regex = "^(?=\\P{Lu}*\\p{Lu})(?=\\P{Ll}*\\p{Ll})(?=[^0-9]*[0-9])(?=[^#?!@$%^&*-]*[#?!@$%^&*-]).{8,}$";
```

Note the `.*?` in the lookaheads is not efficient, I used the reverse patterns (`\P{Lu}` matches any char that is not a Unicode uppercase letter, `\P{Ll}` matches any char other than a Unicode lowercase letter, etc.) in line with the [principle of contrast](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-style.html#contrast).

If you need to support any Unicode digits, too, replace `(?=[^0-9]*[0-9])` with `(?=\\P{Nd}*\\p{Nd})` where `\P{Nd}` matches any char other than a Unicode digit and `\p{Nd}` matches any char other than a Unicode decimal digit.

Comment: It doesn't work for python as it gives issue bad escape \P

Comment: @HimalAcharya Of course, it is a Java solution, the question is tagged with Java and Android tags. In Python, you need to install the [PyPi regex](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) library for these Unicode property classes to work. See the [Python regex matching Unicode properties](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1832893/3832970) post. Also, see [this post of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36188204/3832970) showing how to use `re` to match any uppercase letters.