# How do you update seaborn to latest version (v0.9)?

Tags: python-3.x, seaborn

This is my first question :|

I am currently running seaborn version 0.8.1 in Python3. How do I update to v0.9?

Comment: See e.g. [How do I update a Python package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5183672/how-do-i-update-a-python-package)

Answer (score 14):

Many ways you could do it, the most succinct and straight-forward way may be:

```
pip install seaborn --upgrade
```

If that doesn't give you the correct version, you can specify it explicitly:

```
pip install seaborn==0.9.0
```