# Why doesn't "pip help" list --upgrade?

Tags: pip

One of the key pip3 options is `--upgrade`. So why doesn't `pip3 help` describe it?

1. Do a web search to find how to use pip3 to upgrade a Python 3 package. There are an abundant number of answers, including but not limited to [How do I update a Python package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5183672/how-do-i-update-a-python-package#answer-27183923), all of the general form:

   `sudo pip install [package_name] --upgrade`

   Observe in that command line the presence of the `--upgrade` option.
2. Type `pip3 help` **RESPONSE:**

```
Usage:   
  pip3 <command> [options]

Commands:
  install                     Install packages.
  download                    Download packages.
  uninstall                   Uninstall packages.
  freeze                      Output installed packages in requirements format.
  list                        List installed packages.
  show                        Show information about installed packages.
  check                       Verify installed packages have compatible dependencies.
  config                      Manage local and global configuration.
  search                      Search PyPI for packages.
  wheel                       Build wheels from your requirements.
  hash                        Compute hashes of package archives.
  completion                  A helper command used for command completion.
  help                        Show help for commands.

General Options:
  -h, --help                  Show help.
  --isolated                  Run pip in an isolated mode, ignoring environment variables and user
                              configuration.
  -v, --verbose               Give more output. Option is additive, and can be used up to 3 times.
  -V, --version               Show version and exit.
  -q, --quiet                 Give less output. Option is additive, and can be used up to 3 times
                              (corresponding to WARNING, ERROR, and CRITICAL logging levels).
  --log <path>                Path to a verbose appending log.
  --proxy <proxy>             Specify a proxy in the form [user:passwd@]proxy.server:port.
  --retries <retries>         Maximum number of retries each connection should attempt (default 5
                              times).
  --timeout <sec>             Set the socket timeout (default 15 seconds).
  --exists-action <action>    Default action when a path already exists: (s)witch, (i)gnore,
                              (w)ipe, (b)ackup, (a)bort).
  --trusted-host <hostname>   Mark this host as trusted, even though it does not have valid or any
                              HTTPS.
  --cert <path>               Path to alternate CA bundle.
  --client-cert <path>        Path to SSL client certificate, a single file containing the private
                              key and the certificate in PEM format.
  --cache-dir <dir>           Store the cache data in <dir>.
  --no-cache-dir              Disable the cache.
  --disable-pip-version-check
                              Don't periodically check PyPI to determine whether a new version of
                              pip is available for download. Implied with --no-index.
  --no-color                  Suppress colored output
```

**NOTE** that the word `upgrade` is nowhere in that list of options.

Just to make sure:

3. Type `pip3 help | grep upgrade`. **RESULT:**

   ZERO occurrences are located.

There's probably a reason that `--upgrade` has been excluded from pip3's `help`.

What is that reason?

Comment: Because they're the *general* options, `--upgrade` is listed under `pip install --help`.

Comment: Ohhhh, OK.  I wonder, though, if I would ever have found my way to that unaided...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is listed under `pip install --help`:

```
$ pip install --help | grep upgrade
                              <dir>. Use --upgrade to replace existing
  -U, --upgrade               Upgrade all specified packages to the newest
                              depends on the upgrade-strategy used.
  --upgrade-strategy <upgrade_strategy>
                              dependencies are upgraded regardless of whether
                              requirements of the upgraded package(s). "only-
                              if-needed" -  are upgraded only when they do not
                              satisfy the requirements of the upgraded
```

The flags under `pip --help` are general options.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, "pip" is a different command from "pip install". So, "pip --help" will be different from "pip install --help".

(Kindly add a citation, if someone finds it. )

I use Python2.7 and the options were the same, no --upgrade in "pip --help".

> ` 2019-02-18 10:02:09 ⌚  Utkarshs-MacBook-Pro-983 in ~ ○ → python -V
>   Python 2.7.10
>
> 2019-02-18 10:02:24 ⌚  Utkarshs-MacBook-Pro-983 in ~ ○ → pip -V pip
>   18.0 from /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip (python 2.7)
>
> 2019-02-18 10:02:29 ⌚  Utkarshs-MacBook-Pro-983 in ~ ○ → pip help
>
> Usage:      pip  [options]
>
> Commands:   install                     Install packages.   download
>   Download packages.   uninstall                   Uninstall packages.
>   freeze                      Output installed packages in requirements
>   format.   list                        List installed packages.   show 
>   Show information about installed packages.   check
>   Verify installed packages have compatible dependencies.   config
>   Manage local and global configuration.   search
>   Search PyPI for packages.   wheel                       Build wheels
>   from your requirements.   hash                        Compute hashes
>   of package archives.   completion                  A helper command
>   used for command completion.   help                        Show help
>   for commands.
>
> General Options:   -h, --help                  Show help.   --isolated
>   Run pip in an isolated mode, ignoring
>                                 environment variables and user configuration.   -v, --verbose               Give more output. Option
>   is additive, and can be
>                                 used up to 3 times.   -V, --version               Show version and exit.   -q, --quiet                 Give less output.
>   Option is additive, and can be
>                                 used up to 3 times (corresponding to WARNING,
>                                 ERROR, and CRITICAL logging levels).   --log                 Path to a verbose appending log.   --proxy              Specify a proxy in the form
>                                 [user:passwd@]proxy.server:port.   --retries          Maximum number of retries each connection should
>                                 attempt (default 5 times).   --timeout              Set the socket timeout (default 15 seconds).
>   --exists-action     Default action when a path already exists:
>                                 (s)witch, (i)gnore, (w)ipe, (b)ackup, (a)bort).   --trusted-host    Mark this host as trusted,
>   even though it does
>                                 not have valid or any HTTPS.   --cert                Path to alternate CA bundle.   --client-cert
>           Path to SSL client certificate, a single file
>                                 containing the private key and the certificate
>                                 in PEM format.   --cache-dir            Store the cache data in .   --no-cache-dir              Disable
>   the cache.   --disable-pip-version-check
>                                 Don't periodically check PyPI to determine
>                                 whether a new version of pip is available for
>                                 download. Implied with --no-index.   --no-color                  Suppress colored output
>
> 2019-02-18 10:02:45 ⌚  Utkarshs-MacBook-Pro-983 in ~ ○ → pip install
>   --help
>
> Usage:      pip install [options] 
>   [package-index-options] ...   pip install [options] -r  [package-index-options] ...   pip install [options] [-e]  ...   pip install [options] [-e]  ...
>   pip install [options]  ...
>
> Description:   Install packages from:
>
> - PyPI (and other indexes) using requirement specifiers.
> - VCS project urls.
> - Local project directories.
> - Local or remote source archives.
>      pip also supports installing from "requirements files", which provide   an easy way to specify a whole environment to be installed.
>
> Install Options:   -r, --requirement     Install from the given
>   requirements file. This option can be used multiple times.   -c,
>   --constraint      Constrain versions using the given constraints file. This option can be used multiple times.   --no-deps
>   Don't install package dependencies.   --pre
>   Include pre-release and development versions. By default, pip only
>   finds stable versions.   -e, --editable    Install a project
>   in editable mode (i.e. setuptools "develop mode") from a local project
>   path or a VCS url.   -t, --target           Install packages into
>   . By default this will not replace existing files/folders in
>   . Use --upgrade to replace existing packages in 
>                                 with new versions.   --user                      Install to the Python user install directory for your platform.
>   Typically ~/.local/, or %APPDATA%\Python on Windows. (See the Python
>   documentation
>                                 for site.USER_BASE for full details.)   --root                 Install everything relative to this alternate root directory.   --prefix               Installation
>   prefix where lib, bin and other top-level folders are placed   -b,
>   --build            Directory to unpack packages into and build in. Note that an initial build still takes place in a temporary
>   directory. The location of temporary
>                                 directories can be controlled by setting the TMPDIR environment variable (TEMP on Windows) appropriately. When
>   passed, build directories are not
>                                 cleaned in case of failures.   --src                  Directory to check out editable projects into.
>   The default in a virtualenv is "/src". The default for
>   global installs is "/src".   -U, --upgrade               Upgrade all specified packages to the newest available version. The
>   handling of dependencies depends on the upgrade-strategy used.
>   --upgrade-strategy 
>                                 Determines how dependency upgrading should be handled [default: only-if-needed]. "eager" - dependencies
>   are upgraded regardless of whether the
>                                 currently installed version satisfies the requirements of the upgraded package(s). "only-if-needed" -  are
>   upgraded only when they do not satisfy the
>                                 requirements of the upgraded package(s).   --force-reinstall           Reinstall all packages even if they are already up-to-date.   -I, --ignore-installed      Ignore the installed
>   packages (reinstalling instead).   --ignore-requires-python    Ignore
>   the Requires-Python information.   --no-build-isolation        Disable
>   isolation when building a modern source distribution. Build
>   dependencies specified by PEP 518 must be already installed if this
>   option is
>                                 used.   --install-option   Extra arguments to be supplied to the setup.py install command (use
>   like --install-option="--install-scripts=/usr/local/bin"). Use
>   multiple
>                                 --install-option options to pass multiple options to setup.py install. If you are using an option with
>   a directory path, be sure to use absolute
>                                 path.   --global-option    Extra global options to be supplied to the setup.py call before the
>   install command.   --compile                   Compile Python source
>   files to bytecode   --no-compile                Do not compile Python
>   source files to bytecode   --no-warn-script-location   Do not warn
>   when installing scripts outside PATH   --no-warn-conflicts         Do
>   not warn about broken dependencies   --no-binary 
>                                 Do not use binary packages. Can be supplied multiple times, and each time adds to the existing value.
>   Accepts either :all: to disable all binary
>                                 packages, :none: to empty the set, or one or more package names with commas between them. Note that some
>   packages are tricky to compile and may fail
>                                 to install when this option is used on them.   --only-binary 
>                                 Do not use source packages. Can be supplied multiple times, and each time adds to the existing value.
>   Accepts either :all: to disable all source
>                                 packages, :none: to empty the set, or one or more package names with commas between them. Packages without
>   binary distributions will fail to install
>                                 when this option is used on them.   --prefer-binary             Prefer older binary packages over newer source packages.   --no-clean                  Don't clean up build
>   directories).   --require-hashes            Require a hash to check
>   each requirement against, for repeatable installs. This option is
>   implied when any package in a requirements file has a
>                                 --hash option.   --progress-bar 
>                                 Specify type of progress to be displayed [on|ascii|off|pretty|emoji] (default: on)
>
> Package Index Options:   -i, --index-url        Base URL of
>   Python Package Index (default https://pypi.org/simple). This should
>   point to a repository compliant with PEP 503 (the simple repository
>                                 API) or a local directory laid out in the same format.   --extra-index-url      Extra URLs of package
>   indexes to use in addition to --index-url. Should follow the same
>   rules as --index-url.   --no-index                  Ignore package
>   index (only looking at --find-links URLs instead).   -f, --find-links
>         If a url or path to an html file, then parse for links to
>   archives. If a local path or file:// url that's a directory, then look
>   for archives in the
>                                 directory listing.   --process-dependency-links  Enable the processing of dependency links.
>
> General Options:   -h, --help                  Show help.   --isolated
>   Run pip in an isolated mode, ignoring environment variables and user
>   configuration.   -v, --verbose               Give more output. Option
>   is additive, and can be used up to 3 times.   -V, --version
>   Show version and exit.   -q, --quiet                 Give less output.
>   Option is additive, and can be used up to 3 times (corresponding to
>   WARNING, ERROR, and CRITICAL logging levels).   --log 
>   Path to a verbose appending log.   --proxy              Specify
>   a proxy in the form [user:passwd@]proxy.server:port.   --retries
>            Maximum number of retries each connection should
>   attempt (default 5 times).   --timeout              Set the
>   socket timeout (default 15 seconds).   --exists-action 
>   Default action when a path already exists: (s)witch, (i)gnore, (w)ipe,
>   (b)ackup, (a)bort).   --trusted-host    Mark this host as
>   trusted, even though it does not have valid or any HTTPS.   --cert
>                  Path to alternate CA bundle.   --client-cert
>           Path to SSL client certificate, a single file containing
>   the private key and the certificate in PEM format.   --cache-dir 
>   Store the cache data in .   --no-cache-dir              Disable
>   the cache.   --disable-pip-version-check
>                                 Don't periodically check PyPI to determine whether a new version of pip is available for download.
>   Implied with --no-index.   --no-color                  Suppress
>   colored output
>
> 2019-02-18 10:03:47 ⌚  Utkarshs-MacBook-Pro-983 in ~ ○ →  `