# How to update pandas for jupyter notebook?

Tags: pandas

How can you update pandas? I use jupyter notebooks on a macbook pro. I use my local machine for my projects.

I have no idea where to find an update.

Comment: this is what I got when I searched google with your question title: https://www.google.com/search?q=How+to+update+pandas+for+jupyter+notebook%3F&rlz=1C1GCEU_enIN822IN823&oq=How+to+update+pandas+for+jupyter+notebook%3F&aqs=chrome..69i57j0i22i30j0i390l4j69i60.267j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: I have googled this as well but I do not understand any of the suggestions. Do I type a command into the terminal? The workbook I am using? Where?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I update a Python package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5183672/how-do-i-update-a-python-package)

Answer (score 2):

Inside your terminal run

```
pip3 install --upgrade pandas
```

Or inside your Jupyer Notebook:

```
!pip3 install --upgrade pandas
```

Comment: This may sound stupid, but how do I run something on my terminal? When I run the line in jupyter, it tells me that I have to download additional software for the command line (I am not familiar with the command line, yet)

Comment: your terminal is something you can start from the MAC interface No idea how, I don't have a mac. If you cannot get the terminal running, or you have jupyter open an cannot be bothered to restart after updating pandas outside Jupyter, run the !pip... command from inside Jupyter.