# UrlLib giving HTTP 404

Tags: python, pytube

This is my code (very simple and basic)

```
from pytube import YouTube
yt = YouTube("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wTmFilUkClY")
print(yt.rating)
print(yt.streams)
ys = yt.streams.get_highest_resolution()
ys.download()
```

Then I am getting this error

`urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found`

Please help me fix it....

Comment: you might want to remove those ```<br>``` from your code

Comment: 404 not found is ubiquitous enough that you should be able to understand it using just Google

Comment: What version of pytube are you using?

Comment: I am using v3.9.5

Comment: I was asking about the `pytube` version, not Python

Comment: pytube3 veriosn

Comment: That makes no sense. Please Run `import pytube;
print(pytube.__version__)`

Comment: I am using version 9.6.4

Comment: Upgrade to 10.8.2 and try again. Works for me

Comment: Okay how do I do that?

Comment: How do I update?

Comment: [How do I update a Python package?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5183672/6045800)