# i was creating a REST api using flask and while i was about to test it on postman I saw that error

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful, flask-jwt, python-3.10

```
  File "c:\Users\kally\rest\code\app.py", line 3, in <module>
    from flask_jwt import JWT
  File "C:\Users\kally\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\flask_jwt\__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    import jwt
  File "C:\Users\kally\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\jwt\__init__.py", line 19, in <module>   
    from .api_jwt import (
  File "C:\Users\kally\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\jwt\api_jwt.py", line 5, in <module>     
    from collections import Mapping
ImportError: cannot import name 'Mapping' from 'collections' (C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\collections\__init__.py)
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html  3.10 ...  no Mapping in collections. The [Mapping](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Mapping) was moved to collections.abc.mapping in 3.3 and si deprecated from 3.9 onward but up until 3.8 it was still visible.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on my comment:

As [described in the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html), `Mapping` was moved to `collections.abc` in v3.3 and is deprecated since v3.9 (while still left visible for backwards compatability until v3.8).

Your error stems from using outdated imports - you would need to upgrade the used `pyjwt/jwt` - especially its `/api_jwt.py`. The current version of

https://github.com/jpadilla/pyjwt/blob/master/jwt/api_jwt.py

uses the correct imports since [this commit](https://github.com/jpadilla/pyjwt/commit/30d4c5a7f91e2425211b51c479f2f1e7a37f98b9#diff-6893ad4a1c5a36b8af3028db8c8bc3b62418149843fc382faf901eaab008e380) in November 2018.

Comment: to be very honest i dont understand can you explain it like you are explaining it to a novice

Comment: @gabrielkalango You are using OLD software in your imports. These OLD things use syntax for importing the Mapping class that no longer works (since 3.9). You need to update your modules that are imported:  [how-do-i-update-a-python-package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5183672/how-do-i-update-a-python-package) - this may or may not break other stuff so be careful

Answer (score 0):

That error

```py
from collections import Mapping
ImportError: cannot import name 'Mapping' from 'collections'
```

is saying to you, that there is no `Mapping` in `collection` package. Please check [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html)