# ImportError: No shared library could be loaded, make sure that librtmp is installed

Tags: python, windows, rtmp

I am using Windows 8, and trying to work with python-librtmp. I have followed the steps to install librtmp from here: `http://pythonhosted.org/python-librtmp/`. For me, the two pip install lines worked successfully when run in Windows Powershell. After installation, it says the libraries are in `c:\python27\lib\site-packages`.

Now, I have opened a Python IDE (IDLE), and typed in `import librtmp`. This is giving me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    import librtmp
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\librtmp\__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from librtmp_ffi.binding import librtmp
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\librtmp_ffi\binding.py", line 13, in <module>
    raise ImportError("No shared library could be loaded, "
ImportError: No shared library could be loaded, make sure that librtmp is installed.
```

The binding.py file:

```
import librtmp_config

from .ffi import ffi
from .verifier import verifier

for path in librtmp_config.library_paths:
    try:
        librtmp = ffi.dlopen(path)
        break
    except OSError:
        pass
else:
    raise ImportError("No shared library could be loaded, "
                      "make sure that librtmp is installed.")

librtmp = verifier.load_library()
```

The *init*.py file in librtmp_config folder:

```
"""Runtime configuration of python-librtmp.

   This module provides access to variables used by this library
   and makes it possible to customize some behaviour before :mod:`librtmp`
   is imported.

"""
__all__ = ["library_paths"]

#: This is a list of filenames that python-librtmp
#: will attempt to dynamically load `librtmp` from.
library_paths = ["librtmp.so", "librtmp.so.0", "librtmp.dll", "librtmp.so.1", "librtmp.dylib"]
```

I am pretty new to Python, and this is the first time I am using Python in Windows. When I installed librtmp, it said installation is successful. I exactly followed the steps in the above link. I cannot understand, then why it is saying `make sure that librtmp is installed`.

Is it some path issue or installation issue? I search for a solution online, but nothing helped.

Do I need to install librtmp separately? After some reading I found, librtmp is present in rtmpdump. I have downloaded rtmpdump zip file from windows. But I don't know how to install it. README says, run "make SYS=mingw", but the zip folder has no makefile!

But there is one subfolder in the rtmpdump folder. That folder contains librtmp.dll. If you see above, the *init*.py mentions one librtmp.dll in its library path. Does this mean, I have to refer to this .dll in the *init*.py. But I don't know how to do that.

Can you please help?

Comment: Which python does your idle use? It could be a different build.

Comment: I am using IDLE from the link: C:\Python27\Lib\idlelib. That means, it is using the same Python27, isn't it?

Comment: You can check with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1093322/how-do-i-check-what-version-of-python-is-running-my-script

Comment: Thanks! The version is 2.7.6. That means it is the same version.

Comment: I have updated the post with more information. Please check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolved!!! I copied `librtmp.dll` file from the rtmpdump package into `C:\Python27\DLLs`. 
From the `binding.py` and the `_init_.py` file content I figured, python is unable to locate the dll file. But, still I don't know why it could locate the file in the DLLs folder. I just tried it randomly, and it worked!

If anyone of you can explain the logic it would be great!