# python -v prints out garbage

Tags: python, macos, homebrew, osx-mavericks

It looks like python works perfectly...

```
$ python
Python 2.7.8 (default, Aug 24 2014, 21:26:19)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.1 (clang-503.0.40)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

But python -v prints out all sorts of junk:

```
$ python -v
# installing zipimport hook
import zipimport # builtin
# installed zipimport hook
# /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site.pyc matches /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site.py
import site # precompiled from /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site.pyc
# /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.pyc matches /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py
import os # precompiled from /u


<..................>

   /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/_sysconfigdata.pyc matches /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/_sysconfigdata.py
import _sysconfigdata # precompiled from /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/_sysconfigdata.pyc
# /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/_osx_support.pyc matches /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/_osx_support.py
import _osx_support # precompiled from /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/_osx_support.pyc
# zipimport: found 135 names in /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-5.4.2-py2.7.egg
# /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sitecustomize.pyc matches /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sitecustomize.py
import sitecustomize # precompiled from /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sitecustomize.pyc
# zipimport: found 135 names in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-5.4.2-py2.7.egg
import encodings # directory /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/encodings
# /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/encodings/__init__.pyc matches /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/encodings/__init__.py
import encodings # precompiled from /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/encodings/__init__.pyc
# /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/codecs.pyc matches /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/codecs.py
import codecs # precompiled from /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/codecs.pyc
import _codecs # builtin
# /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/encodings/aliases.pyc matches /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/encodings/aliases.py
import encodings.aliases # precompiled from /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/encodings/aliases.pyc
# /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/encodings/utf_8.pyc matches /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/encodings/utf_8.py
import encodings.utf_8 # precompiled from /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/encodings/utf_8.pyc
Python 2.7.8 (default, Aug 24 2014, 21:26:19)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.1 (clang-503.0.40)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
dlopen("/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/readline.so", 2);
import readline # dynamically loaded from /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/readline.so
```

I installed everything with brew. This is a new macbook pro, updated Mavericks.

Comment: What makes you think this is not the expected output?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I check what version of Python is running my script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1093322/how-do-i-check-what-version-of-python-is-running-my-script)

Comment: I don't understand why this question has been marked as "not reproducible or was caused by typos". This problem is clearly caused by a wrong assumption, i.e. the `-v` parameter should print the version.

Answer (score 11):

If you want the version use `python -V` (with a capital `V`) or `python --version`.

Answer (score 8):

It's not garbage, you're loading up the default python interpreter in verbose mode, these are the dependencies that are needed for it to load.

You'll get a similar set of stack information from any interpreter, in any OS.

from the help menu supplied via running -h:

> v     : verbose (trace import statements); also PYTHONVERBOSE=x can be supplied multiple times to increase verbosity

Comment: The man page's output is a bit more helpful:
        -v     Print a message each time a module is initialized, showing the place (filename or built-in module) from which it  is  loaded.   When  given  twice, print a message for each file that is checked for when searching for a module.  Also provides information on module cleanup at exit.

Answer (score 1):

Just type python --version and you are not gonna see it.