# Difference in Python printing statement in coursera and book

Tags: python

I just joined a course called introduction to python on coursera. They showed like `print "Hello"` or `print 'hello'` is working on their online tool called codeSculptor.

But on my PC its showing an error.

`print ("hello")` is working fine on my PC.

Why is it like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `print('hello')` call is necessary if you are using Python 3.

`print 'hello'` will still be fine in previous versions.

There might be more changes in what you already learned so keep that in mind that differences between 2.7 and 3 are not just cosmetic.

Answer (score 2):

You are probably running Python 3, whereas the class is using Python 2. The print statement is something that changes between the versions - try this to make sure. [How do I check what version of Python is running my script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1093322/how-do-i-check-what-version-of-python-is-running-my-script)

Answer (score 0):

You are likely missing some considerable setup factors on your PC.

1. Make sure Python is actually [installed on your PC](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/starting/install/win/).
2. Read up on [how to run Python](https://docs.python.org/2/faq/windows.html) on your PC

The online course is hiding a lot of the behind the scenes parts that make it more approachable.

Otherwise, please include the specific errors to further debug.