# Python 2.4 subproces.CalledProcessError substitute

Tags: python, python-2.4, python-2.3

I'm trying to add a `try/except` to my subprocess.

```
        try:
            mountCmd = 'mount /dev/%s %s%s' % (splitDevice, homeDir, splitDevice)
            dev = '/dev/%s' % splitDevice
            subprocess.check_call(mountCmd, shell=True)
        except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
            continue
```

The above snipet works, but if the host executes the code on a Python version below 2.5 the code will fail since `CalledProcessError` was introduced in Python version 2.5.

Does anybody know of a substitute I can use for the `CalledProcessError` module?

EDIT:
This is how I solved my issue

```
        mountCmd = 'mount /dev/%s %s%s' % (splitDevice, homeDir, splitDevice)
        dev = '/dev/%s' % splitDevice
        returnCode = 0
        #CalledProcessError module was introduced in version 2.5 of python. If older version do the following.
        if sys.hexversion < 0x02050000: 
            try:
                p3 = subprocess.Popen(mountCmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
                output = p3.communicate()[0]
                returnCode = p3.returncode
            except:
                pass
            if returnCode != 0:
                continue
        else: #If version of python is newer than 2.5 use CalledProcessError.
            try:
                subprocess.check_call(mountCmd, shell=True)
            except subprocess.CalledProcessError, e:
                continue
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> exception subprocess.CalledProcessError
>
> ```
> Exception raised when a process run by check_call() or check_output() returns a non-zero exit status.
>
> returncode
>
>     Exit status of the child process.
>
> cmd
>
>     Command that was used to spawn the child process.
>
> output
>
>     Output of the child process if this exception is raised by check_output(). Otherwise, None.
> ```

[Source](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.CalledProcessError). This means that you need to check whether the process ran by check_all or check_output has a non-zero output.

Comment: Should I use Popen then instead of check_call()?

The bellow is in relation to check_call:

'Note Do not use stdout=PIPE or stderr=PIPE with this function as that can deadlock based on the child process output volume. Use Popen with the communicate() method when you need pipes.'

Comment: That sounds like an idea. Any strategy which enables you to get the result of the process should more-or-less solve the problem, but if I were you, I would only apply this code for old Python. The new Python should use all the juicy features possible.

Comment: The issue is that I won't know what version of python will be in use but I agree I might add something that first checks if python version is 2.5 or above and then chose what to use. Thanks I'll update my post when I get a chance to test this.

Comment: You can determine the version in use. Check out this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1093322/how-do-i-check-what-version-of-python-is-running-my-script

Comment: Thanks for the help @lajos I've implemented the version check as well.

Comment: Out of curiosity: what kind of system is it that requires to use Python 2.4? :)