# Standard solution for supporting Python 2 and Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, module, compatibility

I'm trying to write a forward compatible program and I was wondering what the "best" way to handle the case where you need different imports.

In my specific case, I am using `ConfigParser.SafeConfigParser()` from Python2 which becomes `configparser.ConfigParser()` in Python3.

So far I have made it work either by using a try-except on the import or by using a conditional on the version of Python (using `sys`). Both work, but I was wondering if there was a recommended solution (maybe one I haven't tried yet).

ETA:
Thanks everyone.  I used `six.moves` with no issues.

Comment: There are all sorts of reasons apart from the python version why an import might throw an exception! So conditionalizing on sys.version_info must be the better of the two ideas.

Comment: @nigel222 imports from the stdlib shouldn't throw exceptions; if they do you have much bigger problems. Version-checking is more brittle and doesn't get you anything.

Comment: It wasn't explicitly concerned only with stdlib rather than conditional importing in general. Also "Bigger problems" are more common than you might think, if the system is a desktop maintained by someone with no IT background (hobbyist, university researcher, etc.) I'd prefer to know about them directly rather than having to debug a wrong import that "used to work"!

Answer (score 14):

Use [six](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/six)! It's a python compatibility module that irons out the differences between python3 and python2. The documentation [available here](http://pythonhosted.org/six/#module-six.moves) will help you with this problem as well as any other issues you're having..

Specifically for your case you can just

```
from six.moves import configparser
import six

if six.PY2:
  ConfigParser = configparser.SafeConfigParser
else:
  ConfigParser = configparser.ConfigParser
```

and you'll be good to go.

Comment: That looks...nice, but why isn't the assignment to `ConfigParser` handled by the `import` statement? I would have expected that to be the point of the `six.moves` module.

Comment: ...oh, I see that the `import` statement *is* handling the `ConfigParser => configparser` module-name change. Got it.

Comment: This is the solution that I used and, yes, six is handling the assignment.

Answer (score 11):

This pattern is pretty standard:

```
try:
    from configparser import ConfigParser
except ImportError:
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser as ConfigParser
```

Comment: I would probably comment this noting one is for Python 2 and the other 3+, but yes!

Comment: If you don't want to install extra modules, this is the proper solution.

Comment: Thanks.  I had figured out this solution, but I didn't know it was the standard.  In my case I was able to use six.move, but if I have to use a 3rd party module that isn't handled by six I'll use this.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this:

```
import sys
if sys.version[:1] == '2':
    from configparser import ConfigParser
else:
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser as ConfigParser
```

Read more [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1093322/how-do-i-check-what-version-of-python-is-running-my-script).

Comment: As stated in my question, I had already found *how* to do this but I was looking for the best practices solution and from what I've learned this is the last choice.