# Annotating a formatted list in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, annotations

What is the most appropriate way for annotating a 'formatted list'?

For instance, I have a function which accepts a sequence which satisfies the following(Let's call this a listNode):

1. The first item(`[0]`) is any value
2. The second item(`[1]`) is an iterable of listNodes

...and builds a corresponding tree, then return its root.
So, given a list `["A", [["B", []], ["C", []]]]`, it will return Node A, which has Node B and Node C as children.

How would I annotate such function?

EDIT: I learned that I could use `List[Union(Any, List[List])]` (or, to be more generic, `Sequence[Union(Any, Iterable[Sequence])]`?) to represent such list in function annotation, but is there a way to express how the sequence should be *structured*? (i.e. the first item in sequence should be `Any`, and the second...)

Comment: Are you asking how you would print such a list in the format you want? Or are you asking how you would store it in a suitable data structure?

Comment: @Akshat Mahajan I'm asking how to annotate such list using python's [function annotation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3107/).

Comment: Oh! Well, each element in the slist can be either a List[str] or a str. You want to read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33945261/how-to-specify-multiple-return-types-using-type-hints) about returning multile types. But in a nutshell, the correct annotation would `Union(List[str],str)`.

Comment: @Akshat Mahajan Thank you! But is there a way to express the structure of the list more specifically? Also, edited the question accordingly.