# How do I document :rtype: for a function that returns multiple possible data types?

Tags: python, return-type, restructuredtext, docstring

In a Python docstring how should one document the `:rtype:` for a function that can return multiple possible data types?

For example, if a function can return `defaultdict` OR `dict` OR `list`, based on the functions parameters, how do you document this?

Code example:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def read_state(state_file, state_file_type='defaultdict'):
    """Deserialize state file or create empty state and return it.

    :param state_file: The path and file name of state file to read.
    :type state_file: str
    :param state_file_type: Data type in which state is stored.
    :type state_file_type: str
    :return: Current or new empty state.
    :rtype: ????? 
    """
    if os.path.exists(state_file):
        with open(state_file) as conf_fo:
            state = json.load(conf_fo)
    elif state_file_type == 'defaultdict':
        state = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(list))
    elif state_file_type == 'dict':
        state = {}
    elif state_file_type == 'list':
        state = []
    else:
        raise TypeError("State file type not defined.")
    return state
```

Comment: This is explicitly not a duplicate of question 33945261, not even in any of the answers. It specifically asks about `:rtype:` docstrings, not 3.5+ type annotations (using `->`), which is what the other question covers.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think I just found out myself by stumbling over a similar question: [How to specify multiple return types using type-hints](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33945261/5931892)

:rtype: can be

```
:rtype: Union[collections.defaultdict, dict, list]
```

Answer (score 15):

You can use 'or' explicitly in the rtype

```
:rtype: collections.defaultdict or dict or list
```

variant

```
:rtype: collections.defaultdict | dict | list
```