# Conventional Practice for documenting callback function parameter return types?

Tags: python, return-type, docstring

I am docstring-ing functions which take callback functions as arguments. Client code developers should know what rtype is expected of each passed function.

What is the accepted convention for indicating this in the :param docstring of the function object?

Note: This question is different from [How do I document :rtype: for a function that returns multiple possible data types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37570679/how-do-i-document-rtype-for-a-function-that-returns-multiple-possible-data-typ).

**Edit:**
For now I am using this:

```
:param predicate: Determines when to consolidate two adjacent 
                  MyClass instances.
:type predicate: callbackFunction(thing1, thing2) -> bool
```