# How to specify "nullable" return type with type hints

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting, python-typing

Suppose I have a function:

```
def get_some_date(some_argument: int=None) -> %datetime_or_None%:
    if some_argument is not None and some_argument == 1:
        return datetime.utcnow()
    else:
        return None
```

How do I specify the return type for something that can be `None`?

Comment: bad naming applied in `typing` package. It could be `Nullable[X]` as an equivalent for `Union[None, X]`. Thus no need to explain that `Optional` is not for optional argument https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Optional

Comment: That naming is  so bad. It should be called Nullable[x]. It leads to using nonsensical terms in libraries docs such as "Required Optional fields" in pydantic (instead of just "Required Nullable fields")

Answer (score 638, accepted):

You're looking for [`Optional`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Optional).

Since your return type can either be `datetime` (as returned from `datetime.utcnow()`) or `None` you should use `Optional[datetime]`:

```
from typing import Optional

def get_some_date(some_argument: int=None) -> Optional[datetime]:
    # as defined
```

From the documentation on typing, `Optional` is shorthand for:

> `Optional[X]` is equivalent to `Union[X, None]`.

where `Union[X, Y]` means a value of type `X` or `Y`.

---

If you want to be explicit due to concerns that others might stumble on `Optional` and not realize it's meaning, you could always use `Union`:

```
from typing import Union

def get_some_date(some_argument: int=None) -> Union[datetime, None]:
```

But I doubt this is a good idea, `Optional` is an indicative name and it does save a couple of keystrokes.

<sub>As pointed out in the comments by @Michael0x2a `Union[T, None]` is tranformed to `Union[T, type(None)]` so no need to use `type` here.</sub>

Visually these might differ but programatically, in both cases, the result is *exactly the same*; `Union[datetime.datetime, NoneType]` will be the type stored in `get_some_date.__annotations__`<sup>*</sup>:

```
>>> from typing import get_type_hints
>>> print(get_type_hints(get_some_date))
{'return': typing.Union[datetime.datetime, NoneType],
 'some_argument': typing.Union[int, NoneType]}
```

<sup>*</sup>Use `typing.get_type_hints` to grab the objects' `__annotations__` attribute instead of accessing it directly.

Comment: You can simplify `Union[datetime, type(None)]` to `Union[datetime, None]` -- according to [PEP 484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#using-none), using `None` within a type annotation is always treated as being equivalent to `type(None)`. (The `typing` documentation actually uses `None` in most cases, but doesn't here, which is an oversight).

Comment: @Michael0x2a didn't know that, interesting. Added it :)

Comment: I went ahead and submitted [a patch](http://bugs.python.org/issue28073) to fix this just now, so hopefully the docs will be more consistent about this in the near future!

Comment: The `Optional[T]` type is well-known in the functional programming community.  The reader will not only know that it means `Union[T, None]`, but will also recognise the use pattern that the function shall return None when there is no meaningful answer, there is an error, or the result is not found.

Comment: In Python 3.10 `datetime | None` can be used.

Comment: @MarioIshac indeed. For those interested, see [PEP 604](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0604/).

Comment: I lose track of which latest change goes into effect in what new Python version

Answer (score 58):

You could just use the vertical line `datetime | None` (similar to OR operator):

```
def get_some_date() -> datetime | None:
   # rest of code
```

Comment: Note that the OR operator `|` is only available for type hinting in Python 3.10+

Comment: @PApostol Or in Python 3.7+ with `from __future__ import annotations`.