# Does python typing support multiple types?

Tags: python-3.x

I was looking at typings set up on the web but I was curious if I can have multiple types.  Example:

```
self.test: str or None = None
```

It shows valid on my intellisense but I wasnt sure if it computed it different.

I was trying to implement something equivalent to typescript.

```
test: number|null = null;
```

But I didn't see specific types in this regard.  Pretty much all my items have the option of being None/Null.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to specify "nullable" return type with type hints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39429526/how-to-specify-nullable-return-type-with-type-hints)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use Union https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Union

```
from typing import Union
self.test: Union[str, None]
```

You can use Optional[X] as a shorthand for Union[X, None].