# Python annotations: difference between Tuple and ()

Tags: python, annotations

Since python 3.6 (or 3.4 ? I don't remember) we can annotate a function. Ex:

```
def getVersion() -> str:
```

Now what happens when a function returns a tuple ? We can do that:

```
def func() -> tuple:
```

But if we know the tuple is a tuple of two integers ? I read here: [How to annotate types of multiple return values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40181344/how-to-annotate-types-of-multiple-return-values) that we can do that:

```
def func() -> Tuple[int, int]
```

But it requires to import the `typing` module.

Also I tried that:

```
def func() -> (int, int):
```

And it doesn't crash.

What is the right way ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Annotations can be used for anything you like: they are arbitrary Python expressions (there are ongoing discussions about breaking this in future Python releases, though).

That's why `(int, int)` works as an annotation.  `(1 + 3)` also works as an annotation.

Some annotations are understood by `mypy` and other python type-checkers as *type* annotations: `Tuple[Int, Int]` is such an annotation.

In short: use `Tuple[int, int]`.