# Function annotation with two or more return parameters

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting

When I write an annotation for a function which returns one parameter, I have no problems.

```
def func() -> str:
    return "ok"
```

However, when I write an annotation with two or more parameters, my PyCharm gives me `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`.

```
def func() -> str, str:
    return "ok - 1", "ok - 2"
```

I think that the parameters can be combined with a `tuple`, but I don't think that's the best way to do it.

My question is: how can I properly annotate a function with two or more return parameters?

Please include a PEP link, if any, in your response. I looked for the answer at [PEP 484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484) and [PEP 3107](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3107) and could not find it.

Comment: It should be noted that the second `func` is equivalent to `tmp = ('ok - 1', 'ok - 2')` `return tmp`, making it immediately apparent why it requires Tuple.

Comment: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3107/#parameters

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to annotate types of multiple return values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40181344/how-to-annotate-types-of-multiple-return-values)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use `typing.Tuple`:

```
from typing import Tuple

def func() -> Tuple[str, str]:
    return 'a', 'b'
```

This is appropriate because, conceptually, you are actually returning a single `tuple` containing those values. Note:

```
print(type(func()))
```

Output:

```
<class 'tuple'>
```

Except for the empty `tuple` (`()`), [parentheses are *not* necessary to define a `tuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html), which means that `'a', 'b'` is created as a `tuple`, rather than being separate values gathered into one by the `return` statement.

Comment: `Tuple` is reasonable. It may be too strict [in some cases](https://github.com/python/typing/issues/592), but there isn’t a better alternative without different tradeoffs as far as I can tell.

Comment: @kojiro It seems to me that that would not apply in the case of return values...?

Comment: I think it still applies. The main thing about the signature isn’t that the function returns a tuple per se, but that it return an unpackable with a specific length. There are plenty of sequence types that are unpackable, but no generic unpackable type that also has length and inner-type specifiers. Tuple can specify everything, but is too strict.

Comment: @kojiro I might be misunderstanding you, but is it not the case that functions with multiple return values *specifically* return `tuple`, as opposed to a function with a single return value that also happens to be an unpackable object that knows its length and elements' types, which *would* require such a specifier?

Comment: A tuple is still a single object that happens to be unpackable. That’s what I’m saying. There isn’t a way to express python returning multiple values from a function because python can’t return multiple values from a function. But it can return a sequence, and a tuple is one kind of sequence.

Comment: It seems Python really cannot return more that one parameter. It packs data with a `Tuple` before and unpacks after the return. But it seems to be the best way to return more that one parameter. As say @gmds the function returns a 'Tuple' - one parameter. Thanks to all.

Comment: The key thing here is that `a, b` is the actual notation for creating a tuple. The parentheses are just useful for controlling the order of operations.