# Python type hints for function returning multiple return values

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting

How do I write the function declaration using Python type hints for function returning multiple return values?

Is the below syntax allowed?

```
def greeting(name: str) -> str, List[float], int :

   # do something

   return a,b,c
```

Comment: Actually, a Python function _never_ returns "multiple values". What you are returning here is a `tuple`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to annotate types of multiple return values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40181344/how-to-annotate-types-of-multiple-return-values)

Comment: Also: [Function annotation with two or more return parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56014563/function-annotation-with-two-or-more-return-parameters)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

**EDIT:** Since Python 3.9 and the acceptance of [PEP 585](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0585/), you should use the built-in `tuple` class to typehint tuples.

---

You can use a `typing.Tuple` type hint (to specify the type of the content of the tuple, if it is not necessary, the built-in class `tuple` can be used instead):

```
from typing import Tuple, List

def greeting(name: str) -> Tuple[str, List[float], int]:
    # do something
    return a, b, c
```

Comment: how do i type hint the variables in a single line where i use this greeting function ?

Answer (score 12):

Multiple return values in python are returned as a tuple, and the type hint for a tuple is not the `tuple` class, but [`typing.Tuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html?highlight=typing#typing.Tuple).

```py
import typing

def greeting(name: str) -> typing.Tuple[str, List[float], int]:

    # do something

    return a,b,c
```

Answer (score 7):

Indexing on builtin `tuple` and `list` is now supported.

```py
def greeting(name: str) -> tuple[str, list[float], int]:
    pass
```