# How to specify multiple returns with type hinting?

Tags: python-3.x, type-hinting

So here is what I am looking for

```
def data_loader(filename: str) -> pd.DataFrame and list:
       some code here....

        return df, dataset
```

I've already looked at Yahyas question listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33945261/how-to-specify-multiple-return-types-using-type-hints) on the same topic and was unable to find what I need.

But, I don't want to use union because, as specified in the python docs, it means X or Y, and I want it to specify I am returning both. Is there a particular function I could use to make it specify X and Y instead of or?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to annotate types of multiple return values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40181344/how-to-annotate-types-of-multiple-return-values)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about you return a tuple like `return (df, dataset)` and then set the type hinting to `tuple`. This should solve your problem. If I am not wrong then performing `return df, dataset` actually returns a tuple. You can check that by printing the `type` of the values returned.
Hope this helps :)