# Why does this code generate a Type Annotation Warning?

Tags: python, python-3.x, types, type-annotation

I have python functions with these type annotations

```
def func_1() -> Optional[Sequence[str, List[str], str]]:
    # do stuff

def func_2(a: str, b: List[str], c: str) -> None:
    # do other stuff
```

Why does the following code give me the warning "Expected type list[str, Any]' got 'str' instead" at the line in which I call func_2?

```
result = func_1()
func_2(result[0], result[1], result[2])
```

Does this mean there is something wrong with my type checker, or is there an issue with my code?

Comment: I get far more errors than that, including a *syntax* error. Please double-check this is a [mre].

Comment: This: `List[str, ...]` is not a valid annotation, as far as I am aware... same with `Sequence[str, List[str, ...] str]`.... what are you trying to express there?

Comment: Please post the warning verbatim and provide the value of `result`. Chances are, `result[1]` is a `str` instead of a `list` but it's uncertain from what you've provided.

Comment: The code was only provided to show the two type annotations I used. Of course the function implementation and imports are missing, but if func_1 is guaranteed to return the annotated type (as there is no warning given on that annotation), how could result[1] possibly be a string rather than a List[str, ...]?

According to PEP 484 List[str, ...] is the annotation to be used for lists of string with undetermined length.

I did provide the warning verbatim as given by PyCharm. This is not a question about a specific execution but about the type warning, therefore result does not have a value.

Comment: @J.Grohmann "According to PEP 484 List[str, ...] is the annotation to be used for lists of string with undetermined length" no, it absolutely isn't. `typing.Tuple` works that way, not `typing.List`, which doesn't include any information about expected length

Comment: Furthermore, `Sequence[str, List[str, ...], str]` what is that supposed to mean?

Comment: I have removed the ellipsis notation as that does not affect the warning in any way. I am not sure what you are asking with your second comment. That is the type annotation for a sequence with three elements of types str, List, and str respectively is it not?

Comment: @J.Grohmann no. That is not correct. `Sequence`, like `List`, takes a single type variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Sequence` is not meant to be used with multiple types like this. `Sequence` and `List` are not meant to have structure (meaning, element 1 is always `int`, element 2 always `str` and always exactly length 2).

You should instead use `Tuple`.

Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40181387/4597523