# Set attribute to be multiple types in dataclass - Python 3.9.x

Tags: python, object, oop

I am using the [`dataclass`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) decorator.

For one of my variables, I would for it to be a `str` or `int` type

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Foo:
    test_var: str
    # test_var: int

    def get_example(self):
        return type(self.test_var)
```

I would like for `test_var` to be either a `str` or an `int` when the `Foo` object is constructed; how can I specify two types for an attribute of my class?

Comment: Something like `test_var: typing.Union[str, int]`?

Comment: It looks like it uses [PEP 526](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0526/) annotations. A related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40181344/how-to-annotate-types-of-multiple-return-values)

Answer (score 6):

You're looking for [`Union`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/typing.html#typing.Union):

> Union type; `Union[X, Y]` means either X or Y.

```py
from typing import Union
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Foo:
    test_var: Union[str, int]

    def get_example(self):
        return type(self.test_var)
```

Note that in Python 3.10, you can use the `X | Y` syntax, which is equivalent to `Union[X, Y]` (cf [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/typing.html#typing.Union)).

Comment: Just an note that the `X | Y` syntax can also be supported in Python 3.7+ using the `__future__` import.

Comment: `from typing import Union` is crucial to the answer