# How to annotate a custom types __iter__ to correctly indicate non-uniform returned types?

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

I have a custom type, for which I'd like to enable unpacking its values (a la tuple unpacking, etc.).  The simplest way I know to do this in Python is to implement `__iter__`. This works great at runtime but I'd like however to provide type annotations so that the correct types are returned for each item, for example:

```py
import typing as t
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Foo:
    a: str
    b: bool

    def __iter__(self) -> t.Iterable[str, bool]:
        yield self.a
        yield self.b
```

At runtime, this works as-expected:

```py
string, bool = Foo("Hello", False)
```

However, `string` and `bool` above are reported as `Any` types.  Is there a reasonable way to provide this use-case whilst preserving types?

The real-world type is not easily translate-able to a NamedTuple etc.

Similar-ish to [How to annotate types of multiple return values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40181344/how-to-annotate-types-of-multiple-return-values)

Comment: Runtime doesn't care about type hints. But your hint doesn't say that it's an iterable that yields one string, then one boolean, then stops. (I'm not sure what it *does* say; perhaps an Iterable that yields strings and/or bools, in any order.)

Comment: You'd have to use some kind of Union, and it won't infer the constituent types when you unpack it

Comment: `mypy` *rejects* `Iterable[str, bool]`: 'error: "Iterable" expects 1 type argument, but 2 given'.

Comment: An `Iterable[T]` value indicates an iterator whose `__next__` method has return type `T`. What you seem to want, though, would be a `__next__` method whose return type *changes* as it gets called, which is not something you can specify statically.

Comment: I think that the best you can do is: `-> t.Iterator[Union[str,int]]`

Comment: I think @hussic's suggestion is the most "correct" from mypy's perspective.

I think the ideal solution would be a type annotation with similar magic to `t.Tuple[str, bool]`, but glancing at its implementation suggests that'd be a feature request for the mypy team...


Glad its not just me struggling to come up with something.

Comment: Perhaps the difficulty of this should be taken as a code-smell that perhaps I should look at re-designing things...

Answer (score 3):

The feature you want is very specific to `tuple` builtin, and is supported via special-casing in `mypy` and other type checkers. However, you can tweak the type checker to make it think that your class **is** actually a tuple subclass, so it will get similar treatment on unpacking.

The following works ([playground](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=master&python=3.10&gist=100de2f999d9742408cace59f9eaf1ce)):

```py
import typing as t
from dataclasses import dataclass


if t.TYPE_CHECKING:
    base = tuple[str, bool]
else:
    base = object

@dataclass
class Foo(base):
    a: str
    b: bool
    
    def __iter__(self) -> t.Iterator[str | bool]:
        yield self.a
        yield self.b


p, q = Foo('a', True)
reveal_type(p)
reveal_type(q)
```

[`typing.TYPE_CHECKING`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TYPE_CHECKING) is a special constant which is `False` at runtime (so the code inside is not executed), but `True` for type checkers.

Comment: Thats awesome!  As you say its probably not a good idea for prod code.

Comment: Is this still the only way to properly type __iter__?

Comment: @PawełRubin I don't know anything better. It is a pretty rare corner case, I doubt it will ever be supported in some more straightforward way.