# How to pass generic through type alias?

Tags: python, python-typing

How to pass generic through type alias?

```
a: typing.Tuple[int, int, int] = (1, 1, 1) 

a: typing.Tuple[int, int] = (1, 1)
```

We can customize the number of generics. However:

```
T = typing.Tuple

a: T[int, int, int] = (1, 1, 1)
```

This will not work, unless:

```
T = typing.Tuple[int, int, int]

a: T[int, int, int] = (1, 1, 1)
```

This will not work too

```
T = typing.Tuple[ int , ... ]

a: T[int, int, int] = (1, 1, 1)
```

But my goal is:

```
T = typing.Tuple

a: T[int, int, int] = (1, 1, 1) 

a: T[int, int] = (1, 1)
```

able to customize generic like `typing.Tuple`. How can I do it?

Comment: [ Any , ... ] , when you check with mypy, still gets error

Comment: You want variadic generics, right? With current level of support you can subclass tuple (maybe fake-subclass, with `if TYPE_CHECKING:... / else:...` base declaration) and use it. This feature was introduced in [pep646](https://peps.python.org/pep-0646/) for 3.11+ with 3.10- backport via typing_extensions (except for star syntax change), but not implemented in mypy [yet](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/12280).

Comment: @SUTerliakov, I read that its not in target version feature... can you provide a example of subclass to make it work? because have already tried, wont work...

Comment: sorry, it was my false memory:( Talking about tuple subclass, I meant something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71427735/how-to-annotate-a-custom-types-iter-to-correctly-indicate-non-uniform-return/71699470#71699470), but it still doesn't provide variadic type, unfortunately. So the solution in PEP646 TypeVarTuple. Could you explain your needs in detail, so that we can try to find some workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am not mistaken, this is indeed a bug in `mypy`, which comes down to the type checker wrongly assuming that the type arguments to the generic -- in this case `Tuple` -- are just `Any` during aliasing. (see [discussion here](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/10068))

The workaround is relatively straightforward. You don't assign, you alias on import:

```py
from builtins import tuple as t  # for Python 3.9+
from typing import Tuple as T

a: T[int, int, int] = (1, 1, 1)
b: t[float, float] = (1., 2.)
```