# Typing unpacking of a class

Tags: python, python-typing

When using a tuple in Python and unpacking, types can be automatically deduced by type checkers (mypy/pyright):

```py
t = (33, "hello")
a, b = t  # a, b correctly deduced by both mypy and pyright
```

How can I achieve the same with a custom class (with `__iter__` or something else)?

```py
class T:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 33
        self.b = "hello"

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter((self.a, self.b))


t = T()
a, b = t
```

In the above example, `mypy` deduces `Any` and pyright deduces `int | str` for both `a` and `b`.

Comment: That's not a fair comparison - if you assign `iter(t)` it will infer a broader type too ([playground](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.11&gist=44f6631bfd969cebe99be29bbcf2884b)). The tuple is a _sequence_, there's no type for _"an iterator of this, then this"_.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Edited the question, I am open to solution other than `__iter__`. I just want to be able to unpack my `t` and get proper types for `a` and `b`. I tried `__getitem__` but `mypy` does not recognize a type as being iterable if it's missing `__iter__` (so `a, b = t` is invalid for `mypy`). `pyright` seems ok with it, but adding overload to `__getitem__` to get proper typing seems to break `pyright` (https://github.com/microsoft/pyright/issues/4859).

Comment: Tuples are special cased. You cannot replicate such things, only inherit them. Would you be fine with a dummy method creating a real or virtual tuple?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi My actual `T` is a dataclass, so I already have `astuple()` when needed, but what I'd like is to unpack when iterating, e.g. `for a, b in list_of_ts`, but `astuple` does not solve this.

Comment: I think you'd have to do `for a, b in (t.astuple() for t in list_of_ts):` to get that, sadly.

Comment: Practically, you should annotate `a: int` and `b: str` before the loop. I don't think there is a "proper" solution, but I'd sure like to be proven wrong.

Comment: You can *pretend* that your class is tuple indeed with `if TYPE_CHECKING` base dedfinition, if you implement something similar to a tuple. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71427735/how-to-annotate-a-custom-types-iter-to-correctly-indicate-non-uniform-return/71699470#71699470)

Answer (score -1):

### Why it is impossible

As already pointed out in the comments, the `tuple` type gets special treatment and I am not aware of any way to replicate its `__iter__` method in a way that would be honored by a static type checker. Let me briefly touch on what works and what does not work at *runtime*.

Unpacking does actually rely on the operand being an [**iterable**](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterable). It *always* calls [`iter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#iter) on it first, which in turn calls the object's [`__iter__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__iter__) method. And the `iter` function raises a `TypeError`, if the object returned by that `__iter__` method is not an [**iterator**](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterator) (i.e. something implementing the [`__next__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#iterator.__next__) method as well).

```py
class Foo:
    def __iter__(self):
        print("called __iter__")


obj = Foo()
_ = [*obj]
```

This prints `called __iter__` and then raises `TypeError: iter() returned non-iterator of type 'NoneType'`.

We can for example add `return iter(["a", "b"])` to the `__iter__` method, which will get rid of the error.

But crucially, we cannot simply have `__iter__` return a `tuple` because it is **not an iterator** (no `__next__` method). Therefore something like `return "a", "b"` in the `__iter__` method would cause the same `TypeError`.

That is the runtime side of things. Now for the typing aspects.

Since any sane implementation of `__iter__` would have to make it return an iterator, the only correct annotation would be with (a subtype of) [`collections.abc.Iterator`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections-abstract-base-classes).

The `Iterator` type is generic, but only **in terms of exactly one type**, namely the type of the values returned by its `__next__` method. Here is what the current [`typeshed`](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/main/stdlib/typing.pyi) stub looks like:

```py
class Iterator(Iterable[_T_co], Protocol[_T_co]):
    @abstractmethod
    def __next__(self) -> _T_co: ...
```

Therefore (as mentioned by @jonrsharpe in the comments) there is currently no way to express that an iterator yields something of type `T` at one point and something of a different type `U` at some other point.

The `tuple` on the other hand is generic in terms of an arbitrary (but finite) number of types of its elements. And it gets special treatment from type checkers, even though *technically* `iter((1, "a"))` still works the same way as with any other class (i.e. calling `tuple.__iter__` to get an iterator over the elements).

When **unpacking** a `tuple` during multiple assignment, type checkers essentially overlook that whole iterator business and directly infer the types of the variables from the argument types of the `tuple`.

In your code you actually perfectly demonstrated, how different type checkers may choose to handle this differently, when you explicitly create an `Iterator` from a `tuple`. The statement `x = iter((1, "a"))` will result in `x` being inferred as `Iterator[T]`, but what `T` is can be different. MyPy uses a join (essentially an intersection), which results in `T: object`, whereas Pyright uses a union, which results in `T: int | str`. Either way, there is still only ever **one** `T`.

I suppose that was a very long-winded way of explaining, why it is currently not possible in the Python type system to replicate `tuple` unpacking with any other type.

---

### Workarounds

The simplest workaround for your specific case that I can imagine is to implement a property that returns the dataclass instance as a tuple and annotate it accordingly. Unfortunately, you cannot get around repeating the types in the annotation, but the result will still be what you need:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass
class T:
    a: int = 33
    b: str = "hello"

    @property
    def tup(self) -> tuple[int, str]:
        return self.a, self.b


a, b = T().tup
reveal_locals()
```

The MyPy output:

```
note: Revealed local types are:
note:     a: builtins.int
note:     b: builtins.str
```

And for an iterable of `T` objects, you would have to do:

```py
list_of_ts = [T(), T()]
for a, b in (obj.tup for obj in list_of_ts):
    reveal_locals()
```

The other alternative is to do what @MisterMiyagi suggested in a comment and annotate the loop variables beforehand and make use of the fact that `Any` yielded by an iterator will always be compatible with... well... any type:

```py
from collections.abc import Iterator
from dataclasses import astuple, dataclass
from typing import Any


@dataclass
class T:
    a: int = 33
    b: str = "hello"

    def __iter__(self) -> Iterator[Any]:
        return iter(astuple(self))


list_of_ts = [T(), T()]
a: int
b: str
for a, b in list_of_ts:
    ...
```

`a` and `b` will still be treated as `int` and `str` respectively by any type checker.

This is not ideal, but unfortunately I see no better way around this.