# How to receive multiple return values with type hint syntax in one line in python3.8

Tags: python-3.x, type-hinting

I have a method returning multiple values in python3.8:
I read here : [How to annotate types of multiple return values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40181344/how-to-annotate-types-of-multiple-return-values) that we can mention multiple return types as Tuple[A,B,C] .

```
    def _calculate_lending_share(user_id: str, squad_id: str) -> Tuple[List[int], Dict[str, Any]]:
...
```

But how do i accept the multiple values with type hint on the same line:

```
tokens: List[int], token_borrowed_map: Dict[str, Any] = _calculate_lending_share(user_id, squad_id)
```

The error is :

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: i'm pretty sure you can't

Answer (score 0):

As of now i have identified that we have to do something like this.

```
tokens: List[int] = []
token_borrowed_map: Dict[str, Any] = {}
tokens, token_borrowed_map = _calculate_lending_share(user_id, squad_id)
```

but providing types on the same line is not supported as of now.