# How can I type multiple values returned from a method?

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting

Can someone help me with declaring multiple return types?

I'm doing some dev in python 3+ and I'm trying to define multiple returns for a method. NOTE: Not multiple return possibilities, but multiple variables being returned. This: [Related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33945261/how-to-specify-multiple-return-types-using-type-hints) does not answer my question and I can't seem to find one which does.

When typing, this works:

```
def func_name(self) -> List[ClassName]:
    # other code
    return [object, object, ...]
```

but what I would like to do is something like this:

```
def func_name(self) -> List[ClassName], str, str:
   # other code
    return [object, object, ...], string1, string2
```

How can I clearly define that multiple values will be returned and type them?

Comment: That's just a [tuple](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Tuple), no?

Comment: Yep. I could not find this answer. I'm really sorry for the duplicate. Thank you very much!