# Autocompletion in PyCharm based on type

Tags: python, autocomplete, pycharm

I'm using PyCharm for python coding. The autocompletion in PyCharm is not as good as in IntelliJ (Java). Consider the below code

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
a.
```

In this case, after I press the `dot`, PyCharm gives the full set of autocompletion options. Consider the below case

```
def func_a(a):
    a.
```

Here, to the function `func_a` I'm passing a `list` as an argument. But when I press `dot` after `a`, PyCharm doesn't give any autocompletion options. I know this is because Python is dynamically typed language and PyCharm has no idea to determine what type `a` is.

But is there any way to tell PyCharm the type of `a`, may be in documentation comment or something like that? So, that PyCharm can give valid autocompletion options?

Comment: See corresponding [PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Python 3.5 introduces type hinting and Pycharm utilizes that.

Use

```
def func_name(param: type) -> return_type:
```

Like

```
def func_a(a: list):
```

Note that all type hints are completely optional and ignored by the interpreter. However, Pycharm can potentially help you detect type errors if you use it as a habit.

Comment: Works like a charm in PyCharm :P. Thank you! Is there a way to specify that the parameter can either be a list or tuple?

Comment: Check [this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33945261/how-to-specify-multiple-return-types-using-type-hints). Again note that type hints are not enforced.

Answer (score 1):

This might not answer your question but this will be helpful for those who just started using pycharm for Django application.

PyCharm does not give (It underlines some built in functions with red) **auto-completion** option for Django if you have started project with **Pure Python**. **Pure Python** option comes when you click  on **new project** option from file menu or when you run pycharm to start new project. **Pure Python** is the default selected option on new project page. You should choose **Django** (the 2nd option) to get **auto-completion** option in PyCharm.

Hope this would be helpful for others.

Answer (score 0):

Can do `:` (examples using `list`):

```
def func_a(a:list):
    do_this()
```

Or manually check:

```
def func_a(a):
    if isinstance(a,list):
        do_this
    else:

        raise TypeError("expected type of 'list' but got type of '%s'"%type(a).__name__)
```

Comment: Still, the 2nd part doesn't answer my question. My question is not to perform type-checking. All I require is autocompletion in PyCharm based on type of the parameter passed to the function.