# Autocompletion with type hinting in PyCharm for lists of specific type

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, type-hinting

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52463362/3337089) shows how to use type hinting in PyCharm for lists. But is it possible to hint PyCharm what kind of objects are present in the list? I know a list in python can have objects of different type. But just for the sake of autocompletion, I want this. Like suppose, if I have a `list` of `numpy.ndarrays`, can I hint that so that when I do `obj_list[0].`, PyCharm gives me autocompletion for the `numpy.ndarray`?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pycharm does have some support for this, but not perfect for now (I'm using version 2018.2.4).

For most types, it works well  (built-in types and some simple custom classes are tested):

```
# hint type in function document:

def func(a):
    """
    :param a:
    :type a list[str]
    :return:
    """
    a[0]   # will autocomplete 

# another way, use `typing` module
from typing import List
def func(a: List[str]):
    a[0]   # will autocomplete
```

Unfortunately, both approaches do not work for numpy types now. Pycharm will complain about `cannot find reference ndarray in __init__.py`.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Actually I had a list of my custom class. So, I put `:type images_list list[ImageData]`. It's working perfectly. In fact I even tested `:type images_list list[list[ImageData]]` and that also worked perfectly well. I'm using PyCharm 2018.2.4 (Community Edition)

Comment: For the second way, custom class is not supported. It shows error. Also, when both are used, the second method takes precedence over first one