# Code completion problems using numpy with collections

Tags: python, numpy, pycharm, code-completion

The code completion e.g. in Visual Studio shows me like in the screenshot below, what possibilities I have to code completion my code.

In Python I started to use Linux and the software PyCharm to code now. My problem here is, that the code completion by far doesn't show me the possibilities I have to code completion my code.
I would expect to get here all the methods I can call with `axd['bottom']`. But for some reason the code completion only shows me unusable stuff. Is their some feature to activate a more useful code completion in PyCharm or otherwise is their probably a much easier code editor in that way.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Some example data to display
x = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 400)
y = np.sin(x ** 2)

fig, axd = plt.subplot_mosaic([['left', 'right'],['bottom', 'bottom']],
                              constrained_layout=True)
playerax = fig.add_axes([0.20, 0.1, 0.64, 0.04])
axd['left'].plot(x, y, 'C0')
axd['right'].plot(x, y, 'C1')
axd['bottom'].plot(x, y, 'C2')
axd['bottom'].  

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: You are applying a numpy function to an object that was retrieved by looking it up in a dictionary. In that case to solve the problem you have to type hint what objects are inside the dictionary. See [PEP 585](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0585/). Sometimes PyCharm's linter can solve the types dynamically, but in some cases if you want code completion for collections you need to use type hints so the IDE can suggest the correct type on the collection. See for example [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52773351).

Comment: Also intellisense is the Microsoft's proprietary name for what other IDEs' normally call [code completion](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/auto-completing-code.html)

Comment: Please edit the question to include a [*"Minimal, Reproducible, Example."*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). In other words, the minimal code, error, and data that allow to reproduce the problem by copy-pasting and find it using a search engine.

Comment: Thank you, that means I have clarify which type I have to get this information. Is their a way for multiple assignments as form:     
    fig, axd = plt.subplot_mosaic([['left', 'right'],['bottom', 'bottom']],
                              constrained_layout=True)
to get this information for fig and axd too?

Answer (score 0):

1.Go to code menu
2. Go to completion sub menu of Code menu
3. The following code completion options are available
A. Basic
B SmartType
C Cyclic Expand word
D Cyclic Expand word Backward

Pick each of one, then test to see if it gives you what you want
e.g pick basic, then test, if not satisfied
pick SmartType, etc