# Type hint for nested dict

Tags: python, json, dictionary, type-hinting

The kind of data structure I parse in my Python script is a json file which, after `json.load(file_handle)`, is of type `<class 'dict'>`. So far so good. Now for a function using it as an input argument, I want a type hint for the parsed json. I read in the [typing documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Dict), that for `dict`s as arguments, I should use `Mapping[key_type, value_type]`:

```
from typing import Mapping

def foo(json_data: Mapping[str, str]) -> None:
    ...
```

The json I parse has `str`-type keys and `str`-type values, but more often than not, its structure is highly recursive. Hence a value is more likely to be a `dict` with `str` keys and even such `dict`s as values. It is very nested, until, at the deepest level, the last dict finally has `str` keys and `str` values.

So how do I represent this data structure more precisely? I was thinking something, along the lines of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33945261/how-to-specify-multiple-return-types-using-type-hints), that it might be:

```
Union[Mapping[str, str], Mapping[str, Mapping]]
```

But it does seem to represent only one level of recursion. Is there a better way to type-hint this?

Comment: Potentially relevant discussion: https://github.com/python/typing/issues/182

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nowadays, mypy and other type checkers support recursive definitions. A (somewhat) complete example of a Json type is:

```py
import typing as t

JsonType: t.TypeAlias = t.List['JsonValue'] | t.Mapping[str, 'JsonValue']
JsonValue: t.TypeAlias = str | int | float | None | JsonType

def foo(json_data: JsonType) -> None:
    """Your implementation here"""
```

This should type check.

Answer (score 16):

## simple dicts

you can simply use `Mapping[K, V]` as the value for another `Mapping`. let's say your json looks like this:

```js
{
   "person_1": {"money": 1000},
   "person_2": {"money": 1000}
}
```

in this case you can use a type hint that looks like this:

```py
Mapping[str, Mapping[str, int]]
```

## harder dicts

but let's say you have something more complex, like this:

```js
{
    "person_1": {
        "money": 1000,
        "job": "coder",
    }
}
```

how could you type hint this then? you can use `Union` (from [typing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Union)) to do something like this:

```py
Mapping[str, Mapping[str, Union[str, int]]]
```

but now we would run into a problem with tools like mypy thinking that `our_dict["person_1"]["job"]` has the type `Union[str, int]`

well it is not wrong, that is what we told it after all. something that could help here is [TypedDict](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0589/) from [typing_extensions](https://pypi.org/project/typing-extensions/).

```py
from typing_extensions import TypedDict

class Person(TypedDict):
    money: int
    job: str

# type hint you would use in your function:
Mapping[str, Person]
```

**NOTE:** in python **3.8** `TypedDict` is part of [typing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypedDict)

Comment: Yes, I understand all that, but I have a problem with hinting a type where there the depth of nesting is unknown. You gave examples where there is one level deep Mapping nesting. But my function expects an argument where the nesting depth can be anything between 1 and... I don't even know how many levels, maybe 5, maybe 10? some keys go deep, some don't. And it is like a fractal, the keys have always the same Union of Types (including the Mapping type itself).

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to comment a reply in the above thread but it won't let me without enough reputation (but will let me post an answer).

I would follow along with the answer [vivax](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11609568/vivax) provided and then add the following for unknown data:

```
from typing import Mapping, Any

Mapping[str, Any] # or Mapping[Any, Any] if the keys are also unknown
```

You could also have more granularity by defining your own JSON type