# is it possible to have 2 type hints for 1 parameter in Python?

Tags: python, type-hinting

so here i have some definition for a container class:

```
class Box:
    def __init__(self, x1: int) -> None:

        self._x1 = x1

    @property
    def x1(self) -> int:
        return self._x1
```

Then in my second function, I will pass in this Box object

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, bar_1: Box) -> None
```

Then now, for some cases, bar_1 can also be None...and if i pass none to class Foo, error will come out:

```
"Foo" has incompatible type "None"; expected "Box"
```

so how can i walk around this? does python allow 2 type hints at the same time?

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, bar_1: Box or None) -> None
```

i need help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to specify multiple return types using type-hints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33945261/how-to-specify-multiple-return-types-using-type-hints). Don't let the title confuse you. This is valid for arguments as well

Answer (score 4):

The type hint for an *optional* argument would be, appropriately, [`Optional`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Optional):

```
from typing import Optional

def foo(bar: Optional[Box]): ...
```

Which is just a shorthand for `Union[Box, None]`. More generically, `Union` allows for "multiple type hints".