# Python typing: Describe common properties

Tags: python, oop, python-typing

I have some auto generated code which defines lots of classes with common properties, e.g.
Unfortunately, they have no baseclass, interface etc.

```
class A:
    errors = []

class B
    errors = []
```

how can I describe a type for that? I cannot easily change all these types.

```
def validate(obj: ???):
    if errors:
        raise Exception("something wrong")
```

Comment: `types.Union`? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33945261/how-to-specify-multiple-return-types-using-type-hints

Comment: Sounds like you shouldn't use type-hinting at all no ? What's the end application here, knowing if a class instance has a given attribute `errors` ?

Comment: @MatsLindh Yes, and no - yes for a small set of Classes this would work. But I have dozens of them in this codebase (autogenerated boilerplate api client using swagger-codegen) and listing them all is possible, but troublesome.

Comment: @Overdrivr I want tpye hinting because the codebase is large and complicated enough that it is problematic to trust people to know what types this function can take.

Comment: @Overdrivr The `typing` module has something precisely for this use case.

Answer (score 5):

You need to define a protocol, which is done with `typing.Protocol` in Python 3.8 or later (Earlier versions can find `Protocol` in the `typing_extensions` module.)

```
from typing import Protocol


class HasErrors(Protocol):
    errors: list


# Requires an object whose type supports the HasErrors
# protocol, namely one with a list-valued class attribute 
# named "errors"
def validate(obj: HasErrors):
    if obj.errors:
        raise Exception("something wrong")


class GoodClass:
    errors: List[Any] = []

class BadClass1:
    pass

class BadClass2:
    errors: int = 3

validate(GoodClass())  # will pass
validate(BadClass1())  # will not pass; no errors attribute
validate(BadClass2())  # will not pass; errors attribute has wrong type
```

Comment: Thank you! Do you know if I can mix typing_extensions  and import typing? The codebase is on 3.7

Comment: Yes, that should be fine.