# Make function understandable by pointing on two return values

Tags: python, pep8

When reviewing my code, how can I show to the reader that my function can return `str` or `bool`, is the following example consider a "good practice" ?

I can't find anything about it on the [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) style guide

```
def equal(x, y) -> [str, bool]: # is this ok to write ?
   return 'Equal' if x == y else False
```

Just to be clear: I want to return a string if the statement is true, otherwise return False

Comment: Why not return True?

Comment: Like Scoot says, it would probably be clearer to return True and handle the logic of  `Equal` or `Not Equal` (if you wanted `Not Equal`) outside the function. Keeps the function definition purer

Comment: @ScootCork Why does it matter ? It's just an example.

Comment: I think it was more curiosity around the need for doing it, than anything else. Balaji's answer below gives you the right idea. For more information, here's a more complete answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33945261/how-to-specify-multiple-return-types-using-type-hints/33945518

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want

```py
from typing import Union

def equal(x, y) -> Union[str, bool]:
   return 'Equal' if x == y else False
```

Comment: Is there any other solutions that works for python3.4 and lower ?

Comment: Only a document string is another possibility, which mostly gets ignored by an IDE, but a human being could read it if it want's

Comment: Please see the post pointed by @afterburner . It mentions the details on the availability of typings from python 3.5.