# What do I do if I have different types of possible returns in Python method?

Tags: python, syntax

Usually I make a note which return type a method has:

```
 def my_method(arg1: int, arg2: list) -> dict:
      ...
```

But what do I do if at best a list is returned but in case something goes wrong, `False` is returned. Do I make that clear in the header of the method? If so, how? Like this?

```
 def my_method(arg1: int, arg2: list) -> dict, bool:
      ...
```

Comment: Normally its best to keep the return type consistent, so if something went wrong, either return an empty list, so its consitent, or raise an error.

Comment: @ChrisDoyle Okay, understood! Thanks

Comment: An empty list is [falsey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39983695/what-is-truthy-and-falsy-how-is-it-different-from-true-and-false)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to specify multiple return types using type-hints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33945261/how-to-specify-multiple-return-types-using-type-hints)

Answer (score 0):

As @ChrisDoyle was saying return types should *always* be consistent, as the opposite may cause miss understandings in your users code. However there are some situations in which declaring multiple return types **is needed**. Python provides a standard builtin module called `typing`, from which you can use the `Union` type. You can read more about it [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Union).

For example, to specify a type hint that must be a numerical value you would do:

```
from typing import Union

Number = Union[int, float, complex]
```

Note that at this point `isinstance(3, Number)` will return `True`.

With that `Union` type you would just solve your problem with:

```
from typing import Union

def my_method(arg1: int, arg2: list) -> Union[dict, bool]:
    ...
```

Comment: Why flag a duplicate and then answer this question? The question you linked answers OP's question

Comment: @PranavHosangadi why not? Though the linked question probably solves his problem I wanted to add a further explanation.

Comment: The recommended course of action is to add an answer on the other question if you feel the answers there do not contain sufficient explanation, because that one has more visibility and this one could get deleted in the future.