# Python docstring documentation for dictionary output

Tags: python, documentation, docstring

What is the recommended way to document a dictionary (dict) output in python docstring for a function?

I was looking at a few tutorials including this from [datacamp](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/docstrings-python) but I can't seem to find a good example.

```
def example_function(arg1: str, arg2: list) -> dict(str, dict):
    '''
    Returns a dictionary of examples

    Args:
        arg1(str): description of argument 1
        arg2(list): description of argument 2

    Returns:
        dict(str, dict): dictionary of examples
        <example of output>
```

For instance, I want to show that the output of the above function has the following structure, where `key1` and `key2` will always be in the output

```
{
    "example": {
        "key1": "value1",
        "key2": "value2"
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance, would be great if I could have some reference links as well! :)

Answer (score 0):

First note that this is not called "docstring documentation" but "type hints".
This is exactly what you want: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0589/ (This PEP is accepted as of Python 3.8)
Further reading: the typing module: https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html
This is an example code snippet:

```py
from typing import TypedDict

class ExampleDataDict(TypedDict):
    key1: str
    key2: str

class ExampleDict(TypedDict):
    example: ExampleDataDict

d: ExampleDict = {
    "example": {
        "key1": "value1",
        "key2": "value2"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I was thinking of showing the specific key in the return part of the function, not really the type of return value

Comment: @jrchew Do you mean this ?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33945261/how-to-specify-multiple-return-types-using-type-hints
If not, could you explain your situation in more detail ?

Comment: nope, i would like to show the return message format in the docstring of the function, what keys are available in the return message