# type hints in a Python Google Cloud Function?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, type-hinting, pep8

In a Python Google Cloud Function with a lot of sub-functions in the "main.py", I added type hints ([= return value annotation as part of function annotation](https://medium.com/@thomas_k_r/whats-this-weird-arrow-notation-in-python-53d9e293113)) in pep8 style like this:

```py
from typing import Union

def f1() -> int:
    return 5555

def f2() -> Union[int, int]:
    return 9999, 1111

def my_main_function(request) -> str:
    a = f1()
    x, y = f2()
    return 'Done.'
```

`Union` is taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33945261/how-to-specify-multiple-return-types-using-type-hints), it is needed if there is more than one type hint.

The function cannot get deployed, there is no log about what is wrong, just an orange error log entry that has the same text as the start item above it.

> ````sh
> MY_TIME_ZONE_LOCATION:MY_CLOUD_FUNCTION_NAME MY_MAIL.com {@type:
> type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog, authenticationInfo:
> {…}, methodName:
> google.cloud.functions.v1.CloudFunctionsService.UpdateFunction,
> resourceName:
> projects/MY_PROJECT_NAME/locations/MY_TIME_ZONE_LOCATION/functions/MY_CLOUD_FUNCTION_NAME,
> serviceName: cloudfunctions.googleapis.com, status… {@type:
> type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog, authenticationInfo:
> {…}, methodName:
> google.cloud.functions.v1.CloudFunctionsService.UpdateFunction,
> resourceName:
> projects/MY_PROJECT_NAME/locations/MY_TIME_ZONE_LOCATION/functions/MY_CLOUD_FUNCTION_NAME,
> serviceName: cloudfunctions.googleapis.com, status… ```
> ````

And when I replace the `->` with `: # ->`  so that all type strings are commented out, it works, therefore, the type hints seem to disturb the Google Cloud Function.

Are type hints supported at all? How can I get type hints to work in a Google Cloud Function?

Comment: What version of Python are you using ?

Comment: FWIW, `Union[int, int]` is just `int` and does not match `9999, 1111`. You are looking for `Tuple[int, int]`

Comment: Anyway, make sure you are running Python >= 3.5.

Comment: @DeepSpace Python v3.9, let me check the Tuple.

Comment: @DeepSpace During scrolling through the code, I found one other function in the large script that returned two vars where I had forgotten to add `Union` (or `Tuple`) like in `def f3() -> int, int:
    return 4444, 2222`. I have first tried it with `Union` there as well now, this ran through! Then with `Tuple`, this also worked (with `from typing import Tuple` then). Now I do not know whether `Union` is still also OK since it was not the reason for the error.

Comment: Not sure how this can be put into an answer now since it was a code error which could not be seen in the question and is thus not reproducible. Whoever wants may still try an answer, it would save the question a bit.

Comment: You can edit the question to now include said part of the code that was missing the Tuple, just add a timestamp - you can also add it as an answer and wait the three days required before accepting it. Alternatively you can close the question yourself, [as you have more than 250 rep](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37752/how-do-i-close-my-own-question#:~:text=There's%20a%20close%20link%20under,%22no%20longer%20relevant%22%20reason.)

Comment: @fabc I had seen your comment, I had just forgotten to do something. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments follows that the error was in another code snippet that went as follows:

```py
def f3() -> int, int:
     return 4444, 2222
```

That code was corrected to include `Tuple` (`Union` also worked but is not the default for many types in one type hint):

```py
def f3() -> Tuple[int, int]:
     return 4444, 2222
```