# Python multiple return type hints best practice

Tags: python, typing

Below method has many potential return types based on values in a dictionary;

```py
    def get_config(self, key: str | None = None) -> int | dict | str | list | bool | None:
        return self._config[key] if key else self._config
```

The types I have available in my config file are limited to those specified above but at what point is list specific types redundant? Should I just set Any here?

Comment: yes , i prefer set any while you check all types

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33945261/how-to-specify-multiple-return-types-using-type-hints)

Comment: @Cpreet that doesn't answer the question.... I'm already specifying multiple type hints.

Comment: In something like `get_config` `Any` is the only valid choice IMO, because otherwise you'll assert types for every config member usage, and it is at least annoying.

Comment: It is a bad idea to write a class method which could return an `int`, or a `dictionary`, or a `string`, or a `list`, or a `boolean`, or return `None`. That is five different data-types. How would you know what you are allowed to do with the return value? `return_value.keys()` might raise an exception, or it might not. Depends on whether the function output a `dict` or not.

Comment: @rkr87, my mistake, since so many types are being returned, Any is the best choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so after a bit of reading I figured out what I think is the best way to handle this:

changed get_config method to below;

```py
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self._service: LocalService = LocalService()
        self._config: ConfigModel = self._service.load_json(PATH, DEFAULT_CONFIG)

    def get_config(self) -> ConfigModel:
        return self._config
```

I then used typing.TypedDict to add type hints to the entire structure of my config file;

```py
from typing import TypedDict

class CategoryModel(TypedDict, total=False):
    # All
    enabled: bool
    prefix: str | None
    # Generics
    allowed_ids: list[str]
    method: str
    enable_prefix: bool
    suffix: str | None
    # Ratings
    absolute_buckets: list[int]
    min_votes_required: int
    not_enough_votes_treatment: str
    relative_count: int
    weight_ratings_by_votes: bool

class CategorisationSettingsModel(TypedDict):
    perspectives: CategoryModel
    ratings: CategoryModel
    release_date: CategoryModel
    themes: CategoryModel

class SearchSettingsModel(TypedDict):
    fallback_to_name_search: bool
    filter_words: list[str]
    refresh_cache_days: int

class PlatformParsingSettingsModel(TypedDict):
    enabled: bool
    prefix: str | None
    platform_map: dict[str, list[int]] | None

class ConfigModel(TypedDict):
    api_auth: dict[str, str]
    categorisation_settings: CategorisationSettingsModel
    search_settings: SearchSettingsModel
    platform_parsing: PlatformParsingSettingsModel
    overrides: dict[str, str]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return a data-type (such as `int` or `str`) and not return an instance (such as `863` or `"hello world"`), then the type-hint for the return type should be `type`

```py
class Klaus:
    def get_config(self, key: str | None = None) -> type:
        return self._config[key] if key else self._config
```