# How do I type hint a function whose return type is specified by an argument, when that argument can be a type hint as well as a bare type?

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting

I have a function that accepts a type (or type hint) and returns an object matching that type (or hint). For example:

```
def get_object_of_type(typ):
  ...

x = get_object_of_type(int)
# x is now guaranteed to be an int

y = get_object_of_type(str | bytes)
# y is now guaranteed to be either a string or a bytes object
```

How can I type hint this function to make this behavior clear to static analysers?

The following solution (with Python 3.12 syntax) works for types but not, for example, type union expressions:

```
def get_object_of_type[T](typ: type[T]) -> T:
  ...
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to specify multiple return types using type-hints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33945261/how-to-specify-multiple-return-types-using-type-hints)

Comment: @VishalSingh nope, this question is substantially different. You issue is that `type[A | B]` is not equivalent to `type[A] | type[B]`, and the letter cannot be expressed as the former in `mypy`. In general generic types are not "distributive" - you can't claim that `list[int] | list[str]` is the same thing as `list[str | int]`, for example, because the latter allows `.append(t)` with `t: str | int`. `type` is effectively a "constructor" signature, so this might be safe - or not, I can't quickly invent a counterexample, but it may well exist.

Comment: Honestly, I don't see a point in doing this. What are you trying to achieve? If something is not typeable in python and does not involve magic or at least metaprogramming, it's likely not very pythonic either (the only important exception I know is parent "constructor"'s args/kwargs in subclass). If you're doing this for own classes, I'd rather add `.default()` classmethod, then you can refer to such default-constructible classes using structural subtyping (as in `Protocol`), if necessary, or just call `.default()` directly.

Comment: How does `get_object_of_type` use its argument to produce a return value in the first place?

Comment: @chepner, in context it's a command for getting values from the user (e.g. via the console), so it reads a line from the console and then parses it differently depending on the type of thing it's trying to return

Comment: OK, rather than passing the desired type as a runtime value, can you pass a function with the appropriate return type? Something like `def get_object[T](parser: Callable[[str], T]) -> T`? Then `get_object` will simply return whatever `parser` returns.

Comment: @chepner FYI, that's also [what `argparse` uses](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/994d22bfbb542956be24580323d5b4aeef822c77/stdlib/argparse.pyi#L92).

Comment: Can I rephrase the question? Your function can take an argument of any type but has to return a type as same as the argument. `T = TypeVar('T')`  should work.

Comment: @MSH No, the function takes *a* type, but returns a value of that type. The problem isn't with `type[T] -> T` so much as it is that it won't work with a type hint (rather than a proper type) as the argument.

Comment: I see. So why wouldn't this work: `def f(a: type) -> Any: return a()`.  Assuming the type does not need any argument on `__init__`.  https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.12&gist=6b2bc5857c385b9c1fee174a89e643c4

Comment: @MSH, I think you've misunderstood the problem (perhaps my fault, for which I apologize). The problem here is not what the body of the function should be (it's already written). The problem is how to write a type hint that conveys to static analyzers that the return value matches the type (or type hint) passed as an argument, even if that argument is something like `int | float`. Your proposed solution doesn't do that; if I use your definition and then do `x = f(int)`, static analysers think `x` is of type `Any`, not `int`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the expression `str | int` itself does not carry, at the type level, the fact that it represents a union type. `str | int` has type `types.UnionType`, but *that* is not actually a type at all: it's just a wrapper around two instances of `type`.

One way around this is to just make the caller responsible for "lifting" the union into the type level manually, with `typing.cast`.

```
from typing import TypeVar, cast

T = TypeVar("T")

def get_object_from_string(t: T) -> T:
    ...

reveal_type(get_object_from_string(cast(str|int, str|int)))  # Union[str, int]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to slightly change the API, you can use the following two facts:

- Passing union type expressions to method arguments may not resolve correctly, but passing them to classes in `[]` **do** resolve correctly;
- `__new__` can be type-annotated to return something other than `typing.Self`.

Demonstration at [Pyright playground](https://pyright-play.net/?pyrightVersion=1.1.349&pythonVersion=3.12&pythonPlatform=Linux&strict=true&code=MYGwhgzhAEDmCmAXA%2BgewEYCt7BagZsogJ4AO8A2gCoC6AXAFDTPQAm8%2B0yyAdvAO7cAFKAgAaaAHoAlNAC0APmhU60AHQaGDAB7QAvHCRosOPIRLkKASx6IaQ6QwBO8AG7wwIImXhDtj4n1DPBNcNHMfa1toAB9oCEQne0cXd09vciFiRyA):

```py
class get_object_of_type[T]:
    def __new__(cls, /) -> T: ...
```

```
>>> x = get_object_of_type[int]()
>>> reveal_type(x)  # Pyright: Type of "x" is "int"
>>> y = get_object_of_type[int | str]()
>>> reveal_type(y)  # Pyright: Type of "y" is "int | str"
```

---

This idiom isn't supported by mypy - there's been [an open PR](https://github.com/python/mypy/pull/16020) which may get merged into the future. See also [this comment](https://github.com/python/mypy/pull/16020#issuecomment-1761244557) in the same issue, which demonstrates the same pattern as the answer.

Comment: I don't mind changing the API to have the type passed in square brackets, but note that the `else` clause has to be slightly different: at runtime, `get_object_of_type` can't be an actual function, but has to be some object that supports `[]`. Still, this is easily the closest anyone has gotten yet. The only problem is that - since this answer is not supported by mypy or PyCharm - it's technically useless to me :(

Comment: @JEK ah you're right about the `[]`, that was careless of me. That's easily fixable though a different runtime implementation though, the more unsolvable issue is the mypy thing; I assumed you were using pyright since you used Python 3.12 syntax in the question.

Comment: I'm actually using PyCharm, which has its own type-checking. It supports 3.12 generics syntax but not this level of shenanigans, apparently - I checked with your example. (In fact it doesn't seem to understand `typing.TYPE_CHECKING` at all.)

Comment: @JEK I’m a full user of PyCharm and turn off 98% of its type checking, and I only use mypy. pycharm is way worse than mypy and pyright, but for good reason; laxer typing gives more autocomplete choices, better refactoring analyses, and code jumping. PyCharm understands `if TYPE_CHECKING`, but prioritises the code in `else` if it exists (which is non-conformant with other type checkers’ behaviour).

Answer (score 0):

Rather than telling the function what type you want, tell it *how to get* a value of the type you want from a string, by passing a callable as the argument. For example,

```
from typing import Callable, TypeVar

T = TypeVar("T")

def get_object_from_string(parser: Callable[[str], T]) -> T:
    s = input()
    return parser(s)

def foo(s: str) -> str | bytes:
    if len(s) % 2 == 0:
        return "foo"
    else:
        return b"foo"

reveal_type(get_object_from_string(int))  # int
reveal_type(get_object_from_string(foo))  # str | bytes
```

Comment: Clever, but `get_object_of_type` exists for separation-of-concerns reasons; I have some business logic that occasionally needs values from the user, and some UI code that knows how to get those values and parse them. `get_object_of_type` is called from the business logic, so the caller shouldn't have to know how the parsing works; that's the UI programmer's problem. The UI could work in a totally different way, and probably will in the future, without changing the business logic at all.

Comment: You could define a lookup table like `{int: int, str|int: foo}` for choosing an appropriate parser for `get_object_from_string`. *Something* else is doing the actual parsing; you aren't doing that with `str | int` directly.

Comment: Okay, I think you're onto something here, but in practice I don't have a neat mapping of parsers to desired return types. And I can't make one, because many of those types are expected to be user-defined and don't exist at the time I'm writing my code. For example, if the desired return type is a dataclass, then I make a default parser for it dynamically at run time.

Comment: What does a dynamically generated parser for `str | int` look like?

Comment: "Get input expression. Try to parse it as a string. Try to parse it as an int. If exactly one of those succeeded, return the parsed value. If both of them succeeded, raise an error (ambiguous). If neither of them succeeded, raise a different error (all subparsers failed)."

("parse it as a string" and "parse it as an int" are builtin parsers - I do have some, I just also do the dynamic stuff that makes it so hard.)

Comment: Actually, the function you pass doesn't even need to do anything; it can just be a placeholder that *carries* the type you want. `def get_object(dummy: Callable([], T)) -> T: ...;  def foo() -> str | int: pass; get_object(foo)`. Unfortunately, there's no way to type a lambda expression, so you have to define  named function. You can view this as a more "principled" version of the cast in my other answer.

Answer (score 0):

The following (truly horrifying) solution is probably as close as I'm going to get. It requires the caller to specify the type (or type hint) using type-argument notation, i.e., between square brackets, which isn't so bad.

Unfortunately, since you can't subscript functions at runtime, this in turn requires us to use a `Getter` class rather than a simple `get` function, which isn't very Pythonic. Even worse, since type arguments aren't generally readable from within method bodies, we have to override `__class_getitem__` in `Getter` to actually store the type argument somewhere.

So overall it looks like this:

```
class Getter[T]:
    type_specified = None

    def __class_getitem__(cls, type_variable: type | UnionType):
        class Subclass(cls):
            type_specified = type_variable
        return Subclass

    def get(self) -> T:
        if self.type_specified is None:
            raise TypeError("Cannot get object without specifying a type first")
        # [Lots more logic, including handling the case where type_specified is a union,
        #  parsing input from user, and eventually instantiating something]
        ...
```

Which can then be used like this:

```
x = Getter[int]().get()  # <-- Type checker infers "x" is of type "int"
y = Getter[int | float]().get()  # <-- Type checker infers "y" is of type "int | float"
```

The main reason I don't like this--aside from the general problem of being too magical for most programmers to understand at a glance--is that it relies on the type checker being smart enough to support generic class syntax, but *not* smart enough to understand that `__class_getitem__` is giving that syntax custom behavior at runtime, which in principle should invalidate all its assumptions about what `Get[int]` even means. But as of now, my type checker (PyCharm) is exactly that level of smart, as is MyPy if you use old-style type variables instead of the new kind.